# So this is what "feeling unwelcomed" actually looks like

Tags: discussion, welcoming

In light of this and my most recent experience a few minutes ago I submit this post for discussion. To be extremely clear, I would never condone or excuse in the slightest those that are **actually** rude or abusive, misogynistic, bigoted or racist intentionally or not.

I am adamant that the standing policy of **vote, do not comment, move on** has never been effective and being used against the community at large as a motivating factor in Jay Hanlon's blog post and is counter productive.

> [My first SO qn got so many downvotes so quickly but no one bothered
> to/seemed to be able to answer it. Also, at least tell me what I did
> wrong please instead of just giving a passive aggressive response??
> I’ve always thought that it was my problem until I saw this today. So
> angry](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52)

It seems to be acceptable for an [endless stream of unredacted public shaming of being *unwelcomed*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366890/177800) to be used as evidence that the volunteer community is a bunch of misogynistic, bigoted, racist or just hateful people, but no attempt at a catalog of counter examples of why maybe the volunteer community members might be short, terse or even mildly impolite sometimes exists, until now.

So
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318241/pass-class-method-resultset-into-another-class-method)
is what the volunteer community members that do the actual work
creating the valuable content on your site experience on a
daily/hourly basis. Volunteers that are trying to create a better
experience for their peers and future peers in their chosen industry.

Someone please show this meta question to Jay Hanlon, my experience in the last 8+ years tells me these type of people out number the *unwelcomed* by a few orders of magnitude.

I ( and I am sure others ) want to know where is his blog post to these types of people telling them to be more appreciative to the volunteer community members that **are** welcoming them into the community? It is true because **we are telling it is**! Because the first post is justifying and embolding the behavior documented here.

> I invite everyone that experiences a similar situations that makes
> **you feel unwelcomed and unappreciated** as a contributor to post a screen capture of it here as an answer over the next week or two.

Let's catalog some some empirical experience/evidence as incontrovertible proof they can count that they are not focusing on the root cause of the *unwelcoming* issue.

That way Stack Overflow will know because [we are telling them so](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

I am posting an image because I expect the comments I have flagged as rude and abusive to be removed eventually, they have, and this entire question to get delete voted out of existence once the weekend is over, maybe sooner ( it has ) and I do not want to exclude those that can not view deleted posts.

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318241/pass-class-method-resultset-into-another-class-method]

#### Footnote/Motivation:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnWSK.png) is what someone else who tried to help was well got, for those that can not see deleted content yet. The rude response he got was why I left the first comment I made after I searched up appropriate duplicates with working code for the OP. Then I posted the second comment as a suggestion on an approach.

Comment: If you need to show an example, then at least remove the names. It's really not good style to call out people in such a way.

Comment: @BDL - in practice there is no partial redaction on the internet, if I redacted a name the *exact text* is [easily searchable on Google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=8YT4WvbFAofr_AaJs4CwAQ&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Pass+Class+method+resultSet+into+another+Class+method+&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Pass+Class+method+resultSet+into+another+Class+method). Paraphrasing would not be facts and there would an equal or greater chorus of *links or it did not happen*.

Comment: When [unredacted blog posts are used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366890/177800) as examples of proof *unwelcoming* I feel no moral or ethical obligation to go to the effort, especially when it is easily searchable like I already explained, and already spent effort trying to politely and graciously help someone only to be told *GFY*. Actions have consequences.

Comment: @BDL - it would be extremely easy to just look at my profile and my activity to see what I had voted to close to find the post just as easily as well. So calls for redaction and *not good style* on *calling out people* my part are kind of pointless and come across as an attempt at hand wavy passive-agressive public shaming in their own way, I am not explicitly *calling them out*, I am just posting the facts as they happened.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: I'm not sure how to read "this person was a jerk to me" as anything other than "calling them out". Whatever intent you may have had behind it is irrelevant; you're clearly calling them out on their behavior. And to be honest, this particular behavior is hardly special. It happens; you deal with it and move on.

Comment: @NicolBolas 'this particular behavior is hardly special.' well, it's special in that it won't get any airtime on tutter, and there won't be a blog about it.

Comment: I was an active participant in this exchange, at least at the end, but regardless, I'm not sure how to react to your meta post, other than being confused as to the point you're trying to make. Yes this happens and much too often, but if the OP behaves like this multiple times, the site will block him from asking, so it all usually works out for the best in the end. As for Jay Hanlon and his blog, meh. It has no bearing on the actual quality and utility of this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Thanks for asking this, I am going to add a response to this in the main question, until then; ignoring these users is not the solution anymore than ignoring the vocal minority of users that complain and take personal offense at someone clicking on an arrow or innocently asking for some code. And the later users got a public shaming blog post dressing down the volunteer community from Jay, what do these users get, ignored at best? I do not think that is reciprocal.

Comment: @MartinJames - a blog and twitter feed is in the works ...

Comment: @NicolBolas - so why not the same response to the person that complains about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJdOI.jpg) on an [unredacted blog](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52) claiming *This was just posted by a guy with 100K+ rep on a beginner StackOverflow question.

EQ note: Even this kind of subtly condescending comment can be very discouraging. The words "exactly" and especially "clearly" are warning signs in this context.*, and it is used as I illustrated as proof/examples of misogyny and racism, someone has a double standard?

Comment: @NicolBolas - they were a jerk to someone else first, I was trying to back that person up. It is the internet, I **expect** jerks, what I do not abide by is the attitude of *entitlement* and *hubris* displayed on Stack Overflow, not before Jay's blog post and especially not afterwards.

Comment: No wonder [I still see comments as the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367562/1079354)...they're being thrown around and bandied about without regard for either side.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: You cannot control what other people do; you can only choose what *you* will do. Two wrongs don't make a right; it is no more right for you to post named criticism than it was for the other person. "*it is used as I illustrated as proof/examples of misogyny and racism*" No, it's not. It was used as an example of being *unwelcoming*. Nobody suggested it was racist or misogynistic. The question it was posted on was "MCVE for Not Being Very Welcoming".

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: "*what I do not abide by is the attitude of entitlement and hubris displayed on Stack Overflow, not before Jay's blog post and especially not afterwards." Do you genuinely believe that *anything* you said will change them? When you see unreasonable people being unreasonable, *disengage* and move on.

Comment: I don't understand the need to engage in a communication attempt with such poster. Seems futile :(

Comment: @brasofilo - hindsight is 20/20, no good deed goes unpunished, etc. I can not read someones mind or see the future so how am I supposed to know it will degenerate into *@feelingunwelcome GFY*?

Comment: @Makoto - In all sincerity; If comments are taken as offense that are objectively not offensive, and no comments are take as offensive, then what is the solution? Rate limiting is not a solution because it just takes longer to get offended or causes offense faster because someone is not responding to you quickly enough, only thing I can see that is practical is either just remove the ability to comment or some extremely low threshold for voting to remove the comments completely.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: What part of "***You cannot control what other people do***" was unclear to you? [You cannot stop people from feeling unwelcome by the basic tools of the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366757/734069). So just downvote, close vote as needed, and *move on*. Why do you care so much about some random blog post? What matters are the *actual site policies*. Until that person is actually making site policies, you should treat nonsense as nonsense.

Comment: @NicolBolas - site policies are being proposed and using that blog post as a justification, I disagree with it. That is my opinion, I have a right to voice it. At no point am I proposing to try and control what other people do, that is not even part of my post or an argument against it. That is just changing the topic. What part of *just downvote, close vote as needed, and move on* is not 100% part of the problem. I have to agree with the idea that that policy approach can be see as **unwelcoming** to new community members. Not a personal attack but in general it is **counter productive**.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: "*That is my opinion, I have a right to voice it.*" Yes, it's your right. That doesn't change the fact that you're tilting at windmills. Focus on the *actual policies* that are actually on the actual site, not what might come to be due to some random blog.

Comment: The "pattern" in the answers look good enough for "predicting the future" in some cases...

Answer (score 31):

What you really need to understand is that you will not win. Which is what you keep trying.

- Do what I have told you

  - *Nope*
- I'm warning you

  - *Sure*
- We can't help you this way

  - *Whatever*
- etc.

  - etc.
- etc. etc.

  - You are a very bad man

After the first 2 comments you should have moved on.

Only once they edit their post into a state that there was hope you could have come back with extra guidance or maybe an answer.

Yes, I know that your inbox gets cluttered up with plea's for help, still, ignore it while the post hasn't improved.

Instead of your so much desired end-goal, a well-asked question that is answerable, we have now 2 disgruntled users, you and the OP. And you're obviously so worked up that you continue to let steam off on meta. The escalating nature of comments has to stop, by you and by all the other care bears. You run the risk of being suspended if you push your *help* too far. It is not worth it. Control your self. Stop calling people out.

Maybe (maybe) the first comment should be like this:

> Hi, I'm going to leave a few comments with tips to make your question better answerable. [blah tip 1]. If you have questions on further improvements feel free to ping me. Or you can wait if answers come in based on what you currently have.

This makes clear what your intent is. You have already opted out from any further assistance in case the OP isn't interested in that. The best outcome here is that the OP after a few hours ask for help when no-one has answered or they get the wrong answers.

Most of all: you can stop getting frustrated. Life is too short, be happy.

Comment: knows I already know this, ad nauseum, I am glad they posted for everyone else's benefit. I saw where there was going when they were responding the person that tried and post an answer. I think I am going to start my own *suffering on stackoverflow* blog/twitter feed given how this discussion has been *embraced* by the community and ignored by the powers that be.

Comment: not *letting off steam over this*, just posting what others are experiencing and not posting about because they have been told they are the problem, and we have been told, and the current reasoning of *we know because they told us so*, means it has to be true. And your *first comment* just paraphrased what my first comment said, without, the *ping me*, which is an ***insane*** thing to recommend someone say. **Click here to learn what you need to help us help you**. That is about as welcoming as it gets for anyone, *especially me :-)*.

Comment: I said *letting off steam* because that is how your post came across on me. See those words then as a signal how your post is received. For a casual reader it certainly looks like that and it kind of hides the real message. You've made a point, I'm unsure if your point will be heard but only time can tell.

Comment: there is a saying, *you can lead a horse to water but you can not make them drink*. I have 3 young boys and a wife and her mother in my house, I am used to *not being heard*. I am only interested in the *cassandra* aspect of this post. :-)

Comment: "After the first 2 comments you should have moved on." Okay, but why does it matter if we eventually start using "unwelcoming language" on questions that are already being down-voted and on track to be closed? How does snark or sarcasm somewhere at the bottom of a bad question stand out as the big problem? Sure, it would save some time and frustration to simply walked away, but does it really impact SO? If passable questions were routinely receiving comments like this straight off the bat, I would agree that action was needed but as it stands all the examples have been inconsequential.

Comment: @Lawyerson it might not matter for those involved but we seem to be trying to fight the impression for the lurkers and on-lookers. Seeing snarky comments on every other Q/A pair is not the impression SO Inc. wants to give. I admit I'm one of the blunt users around here and I might be the source of comments that lurkers much dislike. If a slight change in my behavior can help the greater goal I certainly want to give that a try. I don't expect I will get much feedback if I improved much in 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 17):

Stuff..

> Yeah, but where is my answer?  I want my answer!

Blah..

> Yeah, but where is my answer?  I want my answer!

Nice words..

> Yeah, but where is my answer?  I want my answer!

Rude words..

> Yeah, but where is my answer?  I want my answer!

[anything whatsoever]

> Yeah, but where is my answer?  I want my answer!

Yup, this set of OP's are a waste of everybody's time.  The total lack of cooperation, degenerating into rudeness and abuse, does happen occasionally.  It's quite possible that they have no software skills at all, and are just handling someone else's home or paid work for a fee.  It's therefore not possible for them to provide any more code etc. than they were themselves given.

I've stopped commenting, at all, on posts from '<20' users, as a shield against exchanges like this one.

If you do ask for more info, code, data, formatting or whatever, and the OP responds with anything less than respectful compliance to a reasonable request...

Drop it immediately.

Close vote it as 'Unclear'.  Downvote it.  Don't comment any further.  Don't try and justify your original request.  Don't respond to continual bait from the OP.  Don't waste any more time and effort on such questions.

Move on to a good question, else such OP's will drain every drop of blood from your body.

Comment: "Do not comment anything on poor question" is likely to be already a consensus on meta. Unfortunately, we still see many poor questions get immediate comments to teach OP on main site... overeager volunteers...

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: Why are you brandishing that off-site blog as though it were some kind of decisive evidence, rather than a single person's opinion? The "Welcoming" blog didn't even *mention* it, let alone link to it. What does it matter what gets said there? What matters is what policies we have ***here***.

Comment: @NicolBolas - because it is being used as a reference many times on meta as *proof* that the community is women and minorities are targeted for abuse. Which in my 8+ years experience is patently false, almost every *abusive* comment on that blog post is neutral to gender, race, creed, country of national origin and everything else. It is just a record of a few people with internal personal issues blaming the community for perceived attacks that are not there. But it is used as proof **here** in meta to try and shape or justify policies.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: "*because it is being used as a reference many times on meta as proof that the community is women and minorities are targeted for abuse.*" ... where? I've seen it used to show that SO is unwelcoming to new users. But I don't recall seeing anyone use it in defense of the idea that "women and minorities are targeted for abuse" *specifically*. These are [two different things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366665/734069), after all.