# As many have pointed out, comments are the problem then what is the solution?

Tags: feature-request

The first thing they teach you in art school is how to take and give criticism as a professional.

> Criticism is not just a statement to the contrary, it also must
>   contain a reason for the criticism and must be accompanied a proposed
>   alternative solution.

Before leaving a comment basically stating. *You are wrong!* and nothing else, think about how productive that is in the whole. Without the proposed alternative, it is nothing more than a verbose `-1`. Think about how that proves my point about the comment system.

Downvotes on meta mean *"I disagree"*. Why post a comment that basically states *"I disagree and some generic negative comment"* and nothing else, is illustrating the point and just providing objective data to back up subjective feedback. Why not just *down vote and move on*, that is the current community mantra and party line.

For the uninitiated that is almost just as unwelcoming, at least they do not see a comment that they can internalize a some kind of abuse directed as them personally. It is not a solution, that much is clear.

On the main site, the down votes have **real consequences** and the comments are taken as criticism, with no positive alternative solution proposed.

#### Problem: Comments

The [**presumption**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20presumption) of the argument is based on comments are the root cause as evidences in every case cited that people are complaining about.

So comments no matter how neutral are causing feelings of unwelcoming and no comments are considered just as unwelcoming. Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

*I make no assertion that any of these feelings is legitimate. That is impossible because feelings are subjective.* Jay Hanlon is the one that made the erroneous jump to:

> "When someone tells you how they feel, you can pack up your magnifying
>   glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. You’re done. And a lot of
>   devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place.
>   We know because they tell us. I am doing nothing but proposing
>   something to try and change what he thinks is wrong."

The current comment system is the majority source of the *feelings* because of two polcies that exacerbate the inference and amplify things perceptions that are not there or completely unintended.

1. **comments are not for conversation**: that means they are terse, one liners and people are loath to respond to lines of questioning to avoid *conversing*. Which typically devolves into *arguing* because of the *terse* one liners.
2. **vote and move one**: this community *policy* is recommended because of the first problem. It causes its own problems and exacerbates the first one. No follow ups on down votes, close votes, etc. No comments are just as problematic for new community members as *terse* comments with no follow up.

So we should just remove the ability to comment. That much has been [expressed in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367562/addressing-the-highest-friction-point-of-seeming-welcoming-heavily-rate-limitin) ( *which I actually disagree with that proposal, it does not go far enough and is what prompted this post* ) 
and tries to address the root cause of most of the problems that Jay Hanlon's blog post tries to make a point about but gets lost in the clumsy way he blames the volunteer community members that contribute the content to the site that makes it what it is and also whatever financial commercial success it may have.

This is my attempt to address the problem, nothing more.

The in these cases where comments are taken as offense almost always have devolved into a back and forth between one or more people. Which just exacerbated it the problem. Someone feels like they are being ganged up on or ignore at some point.

It is a *damned if you do damned if you don't* situation, has been for the at least last five years, from my experience.

Chat rooms get *suggested* by some heuristic now, usually long after it should have been taken to chat and everyone is pissed and wants nothing to do with any more communication.

#### Solution: Chat

By definition comments are **not for conversation** and they are about the worst way to hold one if conversation was allowed in them.

By definition chat is for conversation and real time interaction, which would go a long ways to changing the *unwelcoming* perception that the *no conversation in comments commenting system* evokes now.

This by no means completely removes the problem that some people are just going to be assholes no matter what, it just removes some of unintended perception that people that are not intentionally being an asshole to a form of communication that is more suited to conversation instead of tossing terse one liners over a fence.

The logical conclusion is that the ability to leave comments be removed.

I suggest that that every question gets a `chat` room instead.

You could make the OP the room owner and moderation would be from the community members with badges in the tags of the question.

Lock the chat room when an answer is accepted or abandoned for some period of time. Make it vote to reopen or something, with previous participants getting higher weighted votes, or flagged for moderation just like comments would have been.

Delete the room when the question is roomba'd, delete voted, has no activity for a period of time or by a moderator just like comments would have been.

The technology is there, refactor it where it will scale to this requirement.

Comment: My dad always said: *Don't argue with a fool in public, because the public won't know which is the Fool*.  Problematic back and forth in Comments will be no better in Chat.  I understand your frustration, but as long as the model allows users to come here with no investment, those of us that are invested will always be at least some disadvantage, and thus have to disengage from the fools.

Comment: Replacing comments with chat makes it *worse*, not better.

Comment: @StephenRauch - that much may be true, but it is just throwing your hands up argument. SO has to try something, because nothing is not being accepted as a solution right now. That much has been made clear. Better to make suggestions that them just do things without any input and spring it on us.

Comment: @Polygnome - that is a statement of opinion, not an argument against it. Constructive criticism, proposes a solution to something that you are negatively criticizing.

Comment: "*The logical conclusion is that the ability to leave comments be removed.*" what logic did you base this on? Blanket policies more often than not return more harm than good from the trivial issues they resolve. Comments are useful, in PHP tag they're absolutely necessary a lot of the time to find out more info, and I imagine plenty of other tags on a regular basis too.

Comment: @James - the presumption of the argument is based on **comments are the root cause**. Constructive criticism, proposes a solution to something that you are negatively criticizing, I proposed a solution. In your comment you just say *you are wrong.* What do you propose is a solution give the presumption that comments are the problem.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome Do you have any data to prove your logic, here?

Comment: @Daedalus - lots of people complain about feeling unwelcome by comments they get, lots of people complain about feeling unwelcome by not getting any comments, there for comments need to be replaced with something. That is where the *presumption* comes in, I am not going to argue that comments are not the root cause.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome Lots of people complain about lots of things, and not all of these things are legitimate.  I'd like to see some SEDE queries or data/research that supports your assertions.

Comment: \*points to people who demand mandatory comments for downvotes\* - they aren't going to be happy if comments get removed because then it would be impossible to comment on downvotes

Comment: @Memor-X:  "You can please some of the people some of the time..."

Comment: @Daedalus - I make no assertion that any of these feelings is legitimate. That is impossible because feelings are **subjective**. Jay Hanlon is the one that made the erroneous jump to. *When someone tells you how they feel,  you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. You’re done. And a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place. We know because they tell us.* I am doing nothing but proposing something to try and change what he thinks is wrong.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome You can show that x number people feel this way.  So far you've posted one question, and that question has a -32 on it.

Comment: @James:  Honestly your remarks do demonstrate one of the core deficiencies of comments *in spades*.  It's fine if you don't agree with the proposal.  It'd be *great* if you posted your stance as an answer so that we could clearly see how you're approaching it.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome One person does not an argument make.

Comment: @Daedalus:  Yeah, that's my heavily downvoted suggestion.  I own the fact that it got downvoted.  That *doesn't* make the points any less valid.  It just means that there's a lot of disagreement with them.  The score can only tell you *so much*, y'know.

Comment: @Daedalus - it is a real time example of what happens every minute of every day on the site. That much is uncontestable.

Comment: @Makoto True.  Such as the various implemented features that got heavily downvoted(as an example of 'votes don't mean everything').

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: "*because nothing is not being accepted as a solution right now*" No, that's backwards: nothing is being accepted as a solution right now. No solutions have been moved forward on. The one you cited was hugely downvoted, and there have been no indications that SO is considering implementing that. Again, tilting at windmills.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Jay made it really clear in his post, that doing nothing was not acceptable. They are going to do something, and without feedback from those of us in the weeds, history shows that it will most likely be the worst possible implementation possible. that quote, got is taken out of context, in context is means *because **(doing)** nothing is not being accepted as a solution right now*.

Comment: Have we considered alcohol? The cause of, and solution to, all of life's problems.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: "*They are going to do something*" And when they actually do something, then you can worry. You're trying to head something off at the pass, when you have no idea what that thing even will be. The *one actionable thing* that post talked about is something we've wanted for a long time: an improved Ask Question screen.

Comment: @NicolBolas - an improved *Ask Question* screen does nothing to address the problem that comments or lack of comments cause. Another off-topic misdirection argument.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: "*I think it illustrates perfectly what new community members are complaining about.*" Only in the sense that you essentially repeat the same points over and over, trying to force the conversation in the direction you want it to go in. The problem isn't SO; just as with your other question, the problem is *you*.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: Yes, it does. If all questions are good, then there won't be snarky comments. If the post you got into that comment thread about had the relevant information in it to begin with, the thread wouldn't have happened.

Comment: @NicolBolas - of course I want to keep the conversation on point, my point. That is kind of the point of a discussion about a point. You stay on it and do not address misdirection arguments. The logical fallacies are endless in that. I am not even going to argue **your point**. You can argue it in a **answer** box. But people put crap in now as quickly as possible, I have been doing GUI workflow for 35+ years, they will still put crap in the question box. Maybe not as quickly but the volume of crap will not subside and the comments about it will not abate.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: There's a difference between wanting the conversation to stay on topic, and arbitrarily deciding that one person's input is off topic because it's not to your liking. That's what you did with James here. He explained why he didn't like your idea, but you decided that such explanations aren't relevant unless you explain an alternative solution to the problem you believe exists. You decided that saying "No, and here's why" isn't good enough and is emblematic of some problem.

Comment: The [presumption](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+presumption)  is the not the topic of discussion, the solution is. So I am not interested in [arguing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6GALVZfR4A) the presumption, especially not spending the entire time countering logical fallacies, that is [not how to argue.](https://www.coursera.org/learn/understanding-arguments)

Comment: I hope this makes it clear. *1)* I disagree with your proposed problem; *2)* I disagree with your proposed solution for a problem I feel doesn't exist; *3)* I offer no solution of my own because I do not agree with the proposed problem and thus feel there is no solution required. Therefore, it's impossible for me to have a suggestion to go along with my opposing viewpoint :)

Comment: Comments are not a big problem for OP's.  The bigger problem is that comments appear instead of an answer.  'My hovercraft is full of eels', would be just as unwelcome as a 'snarky' or flowery, (sorry rene), 'nice' comment - still not an answer that can be copied out, so unfit for OP's purpose.

Comment: @pnuts You know your feature-request tag link points to the main site and not meta? And for 'official' support there is atleast the ['down-votes' tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/down-votes/info)

Comment: @James - then do you acknowledge your last comment and that all your previous comments add nothing to the discussion that a *silent down vote and move on* would, except to probably be interpreted to a new community member ( on the main site ) as more *unwelcoming* than just a silent down vote at best and *hostile/abusive* at worst?

Comment: "*then do you acknowledge your last comment and that all your previous comments add nothing to the discussion that a silent down vote and move on would*" so you go from telling me my explanation is not enough and I should absolutely provide a solution otherwise my comment is just noise and -1, to now I shouldn't even provide a little explanation as to why I disagree and just downvote you and move on? Honestly, I have no idea what you want. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is not in comments.

The problem is that some people lack any tact or patience at times, and that other people can't accept the slightest bit of criticism, however friendly it's worded. This causes people not to be nice to each other.

You're not going to solve this problem by moving the place where these words are exchanged. They're still going to be jerks in chat. That just moves the problem, it doesn't eradicate it.

Comment: I agree it moves the problem, but I propose that it is moving it to a much more management place. Chat is taken differently than comments because *comments are not for conversation*, and I think that is the core issue. There has to be some kind of conversation. Updated my proposal to acknowledge this fact.

Comment: *The problem is not in comments.*, actually they are **in the comments**, your next paragraph states what is in the comments that is the problem and who puts them there. :-) The comment system fosters this behavior and exacerbates the unintended slights because of a couple policies. *comments are not for conversation* and *vote and move on*.

Answer (score 6):

I think my hubris in my feature request to rate limit comments, as well as others' hubris in [excising them completely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366927/1079354) for certain rep levels, as well as the hubris in **this** suggestion is that, whether we like it or not, comments fill a role that the system simply...**doesn't**.

I still agree with you that something needs to be done with comments and commentating on the main sites, but what's going ignored is the vacuum of what actually *replaces* comments.

For simple things like suggesting dupes, you can experience this...

[image]

...but ***most*** of the time, you experience *this* instead.

[image]

The solution may be simply having the close reason(s) better explain what's going on, as it seems to be the case that the community rushes in to fill the gap and void of the system simply not mentioning, "Oh hey, this post is going to be closed as 'unclear what you're asking'.  Here's a few things you can do to fix that!..."

Pushing this into chat would move the chimera from one part of the site to another, and chat has *enough* issues without adding this kind of weight to it.

I plan to put together a better post to actually describe such a feature, when I find some energy...

Comment: your comment on another meta pointed me to yours which prompted this idea and me posting it. I edited my proposal to make that clear. ;-)

Comment: Twice in one weekend I can describe actions I've taken through the week as "holding back"...first with the supercar, and now with a suggestion in an effort to make it more conservative.  I think I'm going to win for losing for tonight.

Comment: I agree with that close reasons need better communication, I would like to add that I think that is only part of the problem. It is something that generates strife, but the strife manifests in the comments, which you can not argue are just a time delayed *chat* session in both the examples in your answer.

Comment: Ironically I experienced the same thing from the same person and quit trying to help @Codingeek, vote move on, hindsight is 20/20 and all.

Answer (score 3):

As others have indicated, it's unclear why you think that forcing people to either write answers or to take it up in chat would help anything.

This *would*, however, have the effect of cutting off discussion. Chat is blocked on many corporate networks, for example, and it would be a pain to have to go to a separate window to see the discussion of an idea. A good percent of people simply wouldn't bother with the extra step and wouldn't bother to get involved in the discussion at all.

If you think that someone is being rude, unnecessarily sarcastic, etc. in comments, just flag the comment.

Comment: **comments are not for discussion** by default, not sure what effect it will have on cutting off something that is not supposed to happen anyway and push it to somewhere it is allowed and the *vote, do not engage, move on* mantra already takes care of the *wouldn't bother to engage"* point, they do not now.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome They're not for **extended** discussion - there's a difference.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome There also seems to be the idea embedded in this that posters are entitled to an explanation of why people disagree with them, which I don't think is the case.

Answer (score 2):

> Criticism is not just a statement to the contrary, it also must
>   contain a reason for the criticism and must be accompanied a proposed
>   alternative solution.

It's not necessarily *even* a statement to the contrary, you can critique and be entirely positive and on side the thing you are critiquing. And criticism by definition absolutely does not require some proposed alternative solution.

> So comments no matter how neutral are causing feelings of unwelcoming

If someone has unwelcome feelings from a "neutral" comment then no comment will ever leave them feeling welcomed unless it's full of rainbows and unicorns and shiny happy things.

**Your Proposed Problems**

> No comments are just as problematic for new community members as terse
>   comments with no follow up.

As is the same as people not bothering to go into chat, and people in chat leaving a terse message with no follow up.

Why do you think chat will magically resolve the issues you raise? There will always be such issues, and I'm all for resolving them if a solution is present, but alas chat is another can of worms and just removes the usefulness that comments provide.

Comments are naturally terse due to the programmed character limitations they have, and because of their purpose - a quick means for information gathering in order to fulfil the site's main purpose - answers.

**Your Proposed Solution to Your Proposed Problem**

> remove the ability to comment [And instead use chat]

You stated:

> By definition comments are not for conversation and they are about the worst way to hold one if conversation was allowed in them

So they are ideal then! Comments are not designed for conversation because that's not the desired purpose, as it doesn't suit the requirement we have. So their being the worst way to hold one is surely a homage to their design and usage?

You are proposing we remove the ability to use functionality that is designed and ideal for the required task, to quickly gather information without long discussions to be able to answer the question. And instead use a system that is entirely designed for long discussions which entirely hinders the "quick" gathering of facts in order to be able to answer?

So, we take longer to get someone their answer? Why would we do this?

If you want more info, ask another question. If it'd be much better suited to chat, each site has it's own chat rooms, jump in one if it suits.

With comments *and* chat we have the best of both worlds, and not trying to shoe-horn specific requirements into the wrong system to cater for them!

**And here are the main points why I disagree with your proposal:**

1. Chat brings about the need to move away from the question area to
   somewhere else - thus takes more time to help and to obtain answers
2. Chat will nearly always bring about extended discussions with
   tangents off the actual question - thus takes more time to help and
   to obtain answers
3. Comments very often provide little titbits and useful info. Put
   this in chat and I can no longer learn something useful in relation
   to the answer I wanted right near said answer
4. Chat is for chatting, comments are for "commenting" on something
   quite specific for a very specific reason and purpose
5. Chat does not in any way whatsoever resolve negativity between people,
   from people, whether hostile, terse, negative, useless, or otherwise
   not welcomed. It just moves it to somewhere that is entirely useless
   in providing the requirements which comments do so perfectly

Often a comment being negative is just due to the nature of the issue being described, not some hostile intent. If your code is very bad and buggy, should I help you by telling you so you can improve and remove bugs/security issues etc, or instead entirely unhelpfully say "aww, I love how quirky your bugs are, nice job"?

I'm not saying we shouldn't be nice, but in return to commentors being nice and helpful, those receiving the comments should refrain from finding hostility and negativity that simply doesn't exist!

People who are hostile are to be ignored and their comments deleted, of course, but people who are terse *and* informative are to be welcomed with open arms in their ability to provide invaluable feedback without time wasting blurb.

---

This is a feature request made by you. You are the one who needs to put forward *your* problem case and proposed solution. There are **no** obligations on me to:

- Vote
- Comment
- Explain why I voted
- Explain why I disagree
- Provide an alternative solution just because I disagree

Regarding our comments to each other under your question:

1. I explained why I disagreed in my first comment, and while terse, was polite
2. You then called me out as doing something wrong just because I offered no alternative
3. We locked horns a bit, however you then used "OUR" locking horns as a means to try to justify your feature request talking about how comments were bad
4. You failed to see the (sad) irony that you were in fact proving that comments can be hateful and used for bad, by the very fact you were being argumentative with me and not processing the opinion I had given, and therefore using me as  some kind of example of a bad commentor

---

I'll leave you with two things to consider:

- Guns don't kill people, people do.
- Comments aren't bad, just sometimes someone makes a bad one.

And...
No-one can hurt your feelings without *your consent*...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time and effort to articulate your position and opinion! And for the record, I agree with a lot of what you say, especially the part about *feelings* being your own problem and not someone elses fault.

Answer (score -1):

PHP will turn into the best programing language ever before I engage with '<20' users about their bad question via live chat.

I would rather wear an Armani suit, sport a P.P. watch, shove $100 bills half-in my jacket pockets and walk though a major city at night.

Why would I want to volunteer to be mugged by OP's?  I have no intention of waking up in an intensive care bed and explaining to cops that it was my fault for being too unwelcoming to thugs:(

Comment: and PHP will turn into the best programming language before `vim > emacs == true` :-)

Comment: Since this was posted as an answer to this feature request, I presume you are fine with comments, but not with chat. So what's the big difference between leaving comments and leaving an equivalent number of messages in chat?

Comment: @Dukeling ' I presume you are fine with comments' - no.  I have stopped issuing them, at all, to '<20' users.

Comment: I find this discrimination over very low rep users a hyperbole, and not very useful in this context. Even med-to-high rep users (1k, 8k, heck, even 16k) can be toxic, more likely to be condescending when so, and those have the privileges to harm their critics even more (revenge downvotes).

Comment: @E_net4 maybe, but it works just fine.  Sub-prime '<20' are not worth typing at.  The risk of 'unwelcome' flagging/tattering/blogging outweighs the rewards of helping new accounts and I'm no longer willing to spend time commenting on them.   Unfortunate, but that's how it is:(