# Should we stop commenting altogether?

Tags: discussion, comments, welcoming

Yes, that's a pretentious title.

I love commenting. I'm on my way to having posted 15,000 comments. I want to help people improve their question so it won't be closed, or help them find a duplicate that answers it.

But I notice useful, non-harmful, non-unwelcoming comments disappearing left and right. Not only mine, but in this case one of mine is indeed what this question is about.

People [apparently can flag comments as "no longer needed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371796/if-so-is-about-building-a-qa-library-how-to-communicate-and-uphold-that?noredirect=1#comment615699_371796) to make them go away and successively refuse to improve their question, removing the comment as a signpost for both other commenters (who then might post the same improvement request again) and later visitors (not seeing any comments, assuming the question is fine).

Yesterday a 150th question was posted by someone with the age old misunderstanding that  *"What have you tried"* means *"Show the code you have that made you end up at this problem"*, and not *"Show what you have tried to solve this problem"*. Big difference.

I commented something along the lines of:

> Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. This is a simple indexof+substring or regex operation.

I posted this comment to allure the OP to edit their question to either show their broken code, or to mention terms they've encountered while searching for a solution.

They responded that their question already contains what they've tried (it doesn't), and a 6K rep answerer supported them and called me a troll. Of course *that* one was flagged by me and it got removed, because they were name-calling.

But my point is that my comment, asking for clarification, was flagged and successively removed.

If that's the current state of affairs, I'm going to stop commenting on bad questions altogether, and thus resort to "drive-by-downvoting", which will ultimately lead to compassion upvotes (*"Why was this downvoted? I don't know either, have an upvote"*), beating the question ban system and devaluating reputation points. Good luck upholding question quality like that.

So: can you pretty please with sugar on top rethink the way you handle comment flags? This feels very unwelcoming.

Comment: The whole discussion revolving around "unwelcoming comments" is enough of a reason for me not to comment on how the question at hand could be improved. It's just not worth the hassle. Nowadays I stick to the good old "Downvote, flag if necessary, and move on".

Comment: I don't see it as 'pretentious', especially as I have suggested something similar, (not quite the same, so not dupe), myself: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366927/758133

Comment: I'm starting to feel it's a lost case. Stop commenting altogether and you'll still see comments going like "it seems we have trolls in this tag randomly downvoting posts". Ideally, we'd think of ways to minimize harm, be it with or without commenting.

Comment: There is nothing pretentious about an honest question revolving around a really noticeable trend. It is potentially the start of a nice meta bash though ;)

Comment: @E_net4 they post the 'random-downvoting trolls' comments/metas already, so no change.  The OP's will always find some way to lash out when a slave-revolt leaves them with no homework to hand in but, at least, downvotes with no comments leaves them with no single target username for a whipping.

Comment: Uh, I'm normally a bit apprehensive about the criticism of the new welcoming thing, but I'll happily upvote this one. Politely asking the OP to provide context should *not* be considered unwelcoming and this sounds like a blatant misuse of the "no longer needed" flag to me.

Comment: I'm in the same boat with 30,625 comments (I like to think usually friendly and often helpful) and I sure as hell won't be wasting my time authoring any more until there is a transparent and sane policy around this.

Comment: A comment containing [“what have you tried”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) and a partial answer. Why do you think your comment should stick around?

Comment: @Dukeling that comment is to entice them to show their research and their code. If they tried something but it failed, they should show that code. If they found something but didn't think it was relevant, they should mention that in their question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, if you think comments containing nothing more than "What have you tried" should be allowed, see the linked post. If you think such comments shouldn't be allowed, the question is why you think your comment is better - all you did was add a partial answer, which, if anything, makes the comment even less appropriate (because comments are not for answers).

Comment: @Dukeling [there's nothing wrong with "what have you tried"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments), when phrased constructively. By commenting what I did, I was asking _"Are you really asking how to find a substring within a string? Because there are thousands of examples about that on the web"_ - but then in a polite, constructive way. That's not a "partial answer", that's pulling out of the OP what they have tried, in order to let them either improve their question or find an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure, but your "constructive" phrasing involved posting an answer, not asking them specifically what we need from them. If an answer is "use IndexOf and Substring like this: ...", then "use IndexOf and Substring" is a partial answer, and "This looks like an ideal candidate for" is just a fancy way of saying "use".

Comment: I'm not sure having something like _"This is a simple indexof+substring or regex operation."_ is in anyway helpful or constructive, and because of that it can be seen as unwelcoming.

Comment: @CodeCaster "I was asking 'Are you really asking how to find a substring within a string?'" - maybe that's what you *wanted* to ask, but that's not what I'm reading in your comment.

Comment: I must agree with Dukeling. People often don't understand what you think they would, especially when they are no native speaker. I personally don't see anything polite in your comment. The "please" could as well be ironic, so that doesn't count. And it would never ever occur to me, that "show the code" could also mean "that made you end up at this problem". I'd say you simply have to work on your wording (given only these two examples. I didn't read any of your 15,000 comments).

Comment: Has anyone else just lost interest in this and carried on as if "the welcoming" didn't happen? Or is that just me.

Comment: I could have sworn that they changed `add a comment` into `suggest improvement`. Where is it? Am I going crazy?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It says that on some SE sites but not all. Don't ask me why.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Is that seriously the bar for "unwelcoming" nowadays? I have not been around much but if so that is honestly scary. Pandering is never the answer. Never.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That I am aware of but wasn't there a proposal/approval to have it done on Stack Overflow too?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It's possible but if so I missed it (but I'm not paying much attention these days)

Comment: @fancyPants It's perfectly polite. The only way it could be more polite is to add smiley face emojis. I honestly can't see how you find it impolite. If by chance you really mean "wasn't 100% necessary to ensure the smooth operation of the question" then (a) I disagree, and (b) even if I agreed, that's a remarkably high bar to set for this mythical "welcoming" notion. At that point, why even bother showing up at all? We literally may as well just all go home.

Comment: @Liam what do you mean? Yes, I could've written that comment in a lot of different ways, and in retrospect I should've. The point is: it is a question that shows no research effort whatsoever, and a duplicate of many. I wanted to get a response from the OP so I could guide them further. Instead my comment got flagged and removed, the OP got their answer, while that answer already lives in hundreds of other answers on the site. So all I'm asking: should I continue to comment (and yes, perhaps try to improve my wording), or should I let that go because the comment could be removed anytime?

Comment: I think you should do whatever you think is right and if SO (inc) don't agree then meh. Without us this site is nothing, I think they (SO) need to remember/be reminded of this.

Comment: Why does it seem like more effort is required to post a comment than is required of people wanting expert help?

Comment: @Plutonix You have hit the nail on the head my friend. And it's because SE is deliberately encouraging entitlement. Scary.

Comment: @Plutonix well, cntl-c/cntl-v is only really two keystrokes, three if you count the control key.  Comments that short are not even allowed.

Comment: @plutonix how very unwelcoming of you(/sarcasm). SE turned into a cellphone provider... 'if you are with us already, then you are owed nothing and tough luck. But to get you to sign up with us, **we will give you the world**. Established curators are few and far between, new users are a dime a thousand....if you make money from traffic, who would you pander for? :/.... Really sad

Comment: @Patrice It's worse, it's Pay-Nothing-As-Someone-Else-Googles :(

Comment: Why was this dupe-closed with a question that is not even remotely related to this one?

Comment: If the question seemed like a duplicate, why did you comment instead of voting to close? Too many people ignore requests for improvements (or really any feedback that isn't an answer) to expect an edit in response to one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree that it shouldn't be considered unwelcoming, but it does read a bit condescending (and IMO not very helpful), and therefore some people **will** read it as unwelcoming.

Comment: BTW the it's not relevant flag allows for more comment leniency, as a discussion about a post is relevant. Doesn't matter if it's no longer needed. Do you hear that sound? it's the rumble of *why was my comment flag declined*  questions

Comment: @CodeCaster asked this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371870/how-does-the-new-comment-flags-affect-our-comments

Comment: @MarkRotteveel When we make a rule that says "everything you write must be completely utterly impossible for anyone in the entire world to read as unwelcoming" it will become infeasible to communicate at all. There is always someone who will misread, or misinterpret, or just flat out decide that something pleasant enough has offended them. We cannot, absolutely cannot, prioritise pandering to this small number of people's sensitivities at the total expense of all other goals, not when one of those goals (keeping the community useful and productive) is of absolute vital importance.

Comment: Bad, poorly written, no-effort questions make me feel unwelcome.  What can we do about *that*?

Comment: @Plutonix: We could put up barriers to entry (opposite to Jeff Atwood's original statement *"no barriers to entry"*). -About 10 years ago; BTW, isn't today the 10 year anniversary of the Stack Overflow beta launch?

Comment: @PeterMortensen **Or** the sign up process could be improved to actually prepare new users for what is expected.  None of the main close reasons are covered as minimal expectations.  They can be found if you go looking for them but it is covered in optional content

Comment: How can you see the comments you've made? I see them in the All Actions section but nowhere else.

Comment: Sometimes comments have more upvotes than the answer itself...FWIW...

Comment: "*People apparently can flag comments as "no longer needed" to make them go away and successively refuse to improve their question, removing the comment as a signpost for both other commenters (who then might post the same improvement request again) and later visitors (not seeing any comments, assuming the question is fine).*" I believe you have mischaracterized Rob's comment with this statement. He said that he would delete obsolete comments after OP has seen them, and also that he would leave a couple relevant comments, not delete them wholesale.

Comment: "and a 6K rep answerer..."  There is so much contempt and passive aggression there!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with that (but I can also see how others can read it), what I don't agree with is the 'shit-storm' of this discussion that somehow that comment (and similar comments) are somehow worth saving from removal. I also disagree with the premise that this is somehow new and tied to the current 'be welcoming' effort. I think it would have been removed in the past as well, it is just this community overscrutinizing everything and then raising hell about it.

Comment: @rogerdpack that's not a fair comparison, you don't quality vote on comments as you can't downvote them. You basically vote on comments so that when they start to automatically collapse, the more prudent ones will stay visible. Different purposes entirely.

Comment: "_This is a simple indexof+substring or regex operation._" is basically one of the examples of unwelcoming comments that was originally shown in the blog post. You don't want to imply that anything is simple, because it might hurt the asker's feelings if they don't see it that way.

Comment: @Lawyerson maybe it is a language barrier, but I am confused by the use of the word "unwelcoming". It is not, it does not imply "get out!" - it implies "do a little better please". It is, in fact, an **unwelcome** comment. As in: the comment itself should end up on the cutting room floor.

Comment: @Gimby Just to play devil's advocate, it could theoretically also be understood to imply "this is the kind of stuff we find simple here, if you disagree this might not be the place for you".

Comment: @YvetteColomb Okay I can read it that way now :)

Comment: I _intend_ to be unwelcoming to lazy, ignorant posters treating this as a read-me-the-manpage service.  If the question took longer to type than the answer would take to discover (say, the poster asking what the right separator for `<paths>` on a command line was) SO _should_ be unwelcoming. Because the question quality has gotten so low it's getting to be simply not worth my time wading through the dreck.

Comment: The problem with a lot of people seems they have zero backbone to take constructive criticism today. A lot of todays developers would have struggled back in the day when out had to crack open a dead tree and try to figure out a solution to their problem and some reason the new generation of developers think they can put in zero effort into asking something and get the solution for free. The 10 years I been on this site it went from people that wanted help with their issues to people that want us to do their work for them. IMO: People that want the solution seem to be the ones that get offended

Comment: *devaluating reputation points* they are already worthless, have been for years, do not see how they can become even more worthless at this point.

Comment: Bad, poorly written, no-effort comments are somehow supposed to be OK now?

Comment: "Yesterday a 150th question was posted by someone with the age old misunderstanding that 'What have you tried' means 'Show the code you have that made you end up at this problem,' and not 'Show what you have tried to solve this problem.' Big difference." I'm pretty sure you're the one with the misunderstanding there. It means, "What information have you found and attempts you've made so far that didn't help?" If all the user does is dump their code and say, "Fix it," at other people, they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's exactly what it say there, isn't it?

Comment: "_They responded that their question already contains what they've tried (it doesn't),_" - It does. It may not contain EVERYTHING that they've tried but it contains the broken code, which IS something they tried. Also what is the word 'simple' doing there other than insulting the OP? I don't think you should have to but here is a More Welcoming (tm) version: "_Please show everything you have tried, not just the broken bit, so that we can narrow it down. This looks like a indexof+substring or regex operation issue. I'd also read [ask] for more tips that'll help us answer more effectively._"

Comment: @Ryan the question doesn't contain broken code. It contains code that is used to obtain a string list. They then, and that's their question, want to take a substring out of each string, after a certain delimiter. The question shows no attempt whatsoever to do _that_. And yes, it's been stated again and again that my comment could've been written in a more friendly way, and perhaps it should've. That doesn't change the fact that comments asking for improvement should not be removed until they're complied with, unless they're insulting, denigrating or otherwise not nice. I find it nice enough.

Comment: I mostly stopped commenting a while ago. I really hate the feeling that I need to walk on eggshells to not get reprimanded or something worse. Sure, I had my fair share of snappy comments, but usually I tried to give the posters hints as to how to solve their problems. But now I have to fear that comments which are considered "unwelcoming" in even the slightest way, will get me into trouble. IMO commenting is simply not worth the effort and hassle anymore and I guess I'm not the only person here with that mindset.

Comment: Seriously, if _"What have you tried"_ is an 'age old misunderstanding' then why are you still using it? Why not just say _"Show what you have tried to solve this problem"_. I don't understand why you'd continue to use a phrase if you know it can cause communication issues and you already have a more effective alternative one to follow up with.

Comment: @Ryan yeah, good point, maybe.

Comment: Ah sorry @CodeCaster, I did go through the comments but didn't notice people had already suggested 'Welcome-ifying' your comment. Yeah, this doesn't address the bigger issue or you real question (hence comment rather than answer) but I even almost didn't post the comment as I figured you are already aware and yeah, I think there are much bigger issues going on. It was an itch that I had to scratch though.

Comment: @Ryan in hindsight I do realise the comment might come across as unfriendly, so I'm not mad for someone pointing that out once again. My point indeed is that I see this deletion happen to many comments, however (un)friendly, and that doesn't invite the slightest bit to spend even more effort to write such comments, as they can be removed at a whim anyway.

Comment: @CodeCaster - if you're arguing for getting rid of comments, should you be commenting here? You've posted seven comments above. ???

Comment: Your post indicates what I dislike, people commenting to get numbers.  I took time yesterday to post code and a very detailed question and immediately get comments about using something else and irrevelent things that tend to have others see them and not give answers you're trying to find.  Or the threads just get long and a PITA to go through when you are trying to find something.  The admins seem to get rid or adjust posts if they have something to do with it.  Also, if the post isn't to your liking, why not just ignore it versus getting number counts up???

Comment: @kfrosty There are no numbers to be "gotten" from comments.  The upvotes just indicate someone else feels the same way and/or would type the same thing.  Also, in my experience the person asking is usually the least qualified to determine what is relevant or applicable.  There are scads of posts here essentially asking *How to drive a nail with a glass hammer?*  There are very often other ways to do things that appear to have not occurred to the OP

Comment: @kfrosty Yeah, and part of the point of SO is that it is mostly user maintained - voting, edit posts, vote to close, vote to delete,  assortment of review queues.  Users who care and want to are encouraged to help that way and commenting on improvements.  I actually recall your "bad names" post from yesterday, but there are no comments at all on it...already have those swept under the rug?

Comment: @kfrosty if you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658493/), the analysis of that is worth an own post. You're asking _"How to make this reflection clone code I found online also recursively copy collections"_. First of all, you're reinventing AutoMapper. Second, you're not showing any effort of solving _that particular problem_, just as the post in question here. You only show non-working code for the problem you're trying to solve. Third, how to copy generic collections is described in duplicates. There are no comments there anymore, but I hope they pointed that out.

Comment: haven't seen anyone mention that "comments are not for answers" and deleting those quick one-sentence "answering comment" is frustrating because quick one-sentence "actual answers" are very often downvoted because not helpful enough - though complete answers! - which again penalizes someone trying to improve the site with an answer vs. the original low-quality question which will not get improved.  Incentives are running the wrong way.

Comment: This is the most depressing meta-question&answers I've ever seen. Clearly the tide is turning. This isn't just rants and FUD: new policy is actively preventing curators to improve this site. Yet there is no constructive response from the higher-ups. I'll take a break and hope for the better in a few months.

Comment: It seems to me that part of the problem is that we don't really effectively work with questioners to improve their poor questions any more.  A poor question can get downvoted and held or closed in just a few minutes.  The OP is likely to shrug and go away rather than taking the time to fix.  Even if the OP does take the time to fix, the damage has been done: there's no guarantee that the fixed question will be reopened, and there's less guarantee that the downvotes will be reversed.  So the OP that walks away isn't even that wrong, since the likelihood that fixing it will help is so low.

Comment: 'we don't really effectively work with questioners to improve their poor questions any more' - well, yes but, to curators, that is a solution, not a problem. Trying to actively help with bad questions is usually a waste of time, often frustrating and occasionally generates rude and abusive responses for which there is no effective sanction. Volunteer time is better spent on handling good questions. OK, on some tags, only ~10% of the questions are worth looking at any further than the title, (today, Sunday, C tag), but it's still a better use of time to ignore and/or down/close vote the 90%.

Comment: You know, apart from your infantile attitude of "things aren't going my way, so I'll stop doing anything (frowny face)" I'd like to post this non-unwelcoming, non-threathening, non-yadda-yadda comment with the hope that when I point out repeating a sentence to a person who does not understand it doesn't suddenly, magically make them completely comprehend it might make you think that "Hmmm, maybe helping people *understand* things is better than blindly repeating them and claiming I did something useful.".

Comment: Poor beginners. Sometimes comments done on their posts don't welcome them. Of course a beginner question might be naïve, not really clear, taking the whole subject the wrong way. Stackoverflow is here to help them, not to send them a general link or a cold sentence. Is it the hundred Null pointer or class cast exception you explain how to solve ? Continue to explain each time how on the case of the beginner. Don't send him away by a rude comment. Be tolerant, comprehensive. We all been (and will be again) beginners.

Comment: @Marc This is not supposed to be a tutorial site or a replacement for books. It's in nobody's best interest (except the solitary unreading individual) to continually spam duplicate beginner content across the web. It doesn't even help the OP, not really, despite what they think (teach a man to fish, man...). This fact is _literally_ the entire purpose that Stack Overflow exists, to set it apart from places like Experts Exchange who were like this. Like, literally the entire purpose. Why has everybody forgotten that?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Yes. In fact, you should probably stop participating at all. No, I am not being facetious.

Stack Exchange has made it pretty clear with their most recent policy nonsense that they are no longer interested in the founding tenets of Stack Overflow - high-quality questions and answers by professional programmers. To me, a "professional" is not defined only by experience and skill but by participation; I would consider everyone who has worked to build SO over the years by e.g. posting comments trying to point new users in the right direction, voting on Meta, and/or working review queues as professionals. To put it bluntly, *professional programmers are those who give a sh*t*.

As can be seen by the above definition, the hordes of Elbonian vampires invading Stack Overflow are decidedly **not** professionals. Yet it has become harder and harder to prevent them from cluttering the site with garbage (see: removal of question close reasons, redefinition of "not an answer" flag to be ever-narrower), and under the auspices of "welcoming comments only", it will become even more difficult. Why?

Simple: it's because Stack Exchange is no longer interested in professional programmers as users of this site; they just want warm bodies to drive page and ad views. There are a lot more Elbonian vampires than professionals, and Stack Exchange is a business: they're naturally going to optimise for what makes them money.

So in short, **professional programmers are no longer welcome on Stack Overflow because we are less valuable to Stack Exchange than Elbonians**. Any contribution a professional makes - regardless if it's the most beautiful, thorough, well-researched question or answer that could touch the face of God - is worth *less* than one of indeterminate value from an Elbonian, since most professionals don't see ads due to high rep.

It's time to accept that Stack Overflow, as a place for professional programmers, is dead. Walk away, don't look back, find another community that is willing to welcome you for your deserving contributions. You deserve better. True professionals deserve better.

**Stack Exchange management is not going to stop chasing the almighty dollar, regardless of what they may claim. Stop wasting your time and effort on a lost cause.**

Comment: This seems to be the case, since the new code of conduct puts much more emphasis on being welcoming than on putting actual effort into the question you're asking

Comment: _Elbonian vampires_???? Wtf is your problem with Elbonia?

Comment: @yivi: Not sure if joke, but Ian is referring to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269289/our-words-are-too-complicated-lets-make-them-simpler

Comment: @Nathan In jest or not, I have to say I do not find it in good taste. Replace it with whatever country you are from, or group you identify with, and I'm pretty sure most people wouldn't be comfortable being in the receiving end of that.

Comment: There's a bit of a non-sequitur here: high-rep users don't *personally* see ads, of course, but since their *posts* drive hundreds of thousands/millions/tens of millions of views, they should presumably still be valuable on that basis. (See tediously inaccurate "Impact" stat introduction, if you like.)

Comment: I see nothing in the new code of conduct that says anything about quality. I don't understand why whenever we talk about being more welcoming the claim is made that welcoming means to accept crappy questions. **It doesn't**. It just means that questions should be closed without being unfriendly. You know what makes me feel unwelcome? This whole insisting that being nice can't go together with keeping the quality up.

Comment: @BDL Wouldn't it be better to be a little unfriendly, but have the author improve the question, instead of just silently closing it? How is closing the question without any explanation _welcoming_?

Comment: @mag_zbc Close reasons include explanations, and an oportunity to edit/improve the question so it gets reopened.

Comment: @yivi Just to be sure - you're aware that Elbonia is a fictional country, from the Dilbert comics?

Comment: @S.L.Barth So sad. I will leave all my comments here so my shame is public for all eternity. In my defense, I have only slept three hours... but I was thinking of **Estonia**. So, so sad.

Comment: @yivi Don't worry, happens to the best. Your concern does you credit.

Comment: @BDL Regardless of the *intention* of the rule changes, the *effect* has been a chilling one because any comment flagged as "unwelcoming" has apparently been handled as such by moderators **regardless of how unwelcoming it is or not**, with the result that legitimately useful/good faith comments have been removed. The end result is detrimental to quality.

Comment: @IanKemp: "*any comment flagged as "unwelcoming" has apparently been handled as such by moderators regardless of how unwelcoming it is or not,*" [citation needed]. Specifically, the notion that "any comment" is handled that way. There was a post here yesterday by a user who tried to do this but was declined twice. So it doesn't seem like the mods are doing what you're saying they're doing.

Comment: @mag_zbc If we just had a closed banner that says "CLOSED, THIS ISN'T UP TO PAR WITH OUR STANDARDS", I would agree. But there's not one close reason that doesn't have a nice explanatory text that helps you figure out what your question is missing. And most of the time, when people come to meta to say "MY POST IS DOWNVOTED WITH NO EXPLANATIONS", they have at least one (often multiple) comments explaining what the question could be edited with. They just disregard it....

Comment: @IanKemp You are telling people to leave and yet you're still here? Hmm... are you calling yourself an Elbonian?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time I've seen a forum post that said, "[they] don't care about us, they just want money", I'd have more money than the uncaring corporations. Unless SO is planning to get rich solely by coasting on past successes, it would be self-defeating to lower the site's quality in favor of short-term gains. We do need to be mindful of overdoing the "politeness clean-up", but ascribing SO's motivations to greed rather than a sincere desire to make SO better is trite and unfair. Not to mention rude to Elbonians.

Comment: Why in conversations about this topic is it always **binary**? Are there really no points on the curve between "pristine utopia of quality" and "eternal cesspool of garbage"? I mean, certainly one understands the incentives but you're casting things in what seems to be rather absolute terms.

Comment: `Stack Overflow, as a place for professional programmers, is dead` I was pretty sure I heard the sound of SO circling the drain when the Help and Improvement queue came out.  Its pretty bad when the smart kids have to answer the questions **and** ask / rewrite them.  If you are not smart enough or cant be bothered to take the time to compose a cogent post, why should anyone read it let alone answer it? (ESL not included).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Or further back, [it comes from Dilbert](https://www.google.com/search?q=dilbert+elbonia&tbm=isch)

Comment: I completely agree. SO is overreacting to a blog post of someone who also  overreacted. Enough of the faux outrage from people getting free help from experts.

Comment: Is it possible to award a bounty to a Meta answer? @Jeff They're not overreacting to a blog post. They're joining a social/political movement, on the most destructive side. https://youtu.be/8PuxuGamWUM Just go read the "Time to Take a Stand" post to see an explicit example of their mindset.

Comment: On the plus side, it's welcoming to find a Q&A get thsi far without degenerating into vapid exchange about misogyny and prejudice against the People Of Cobol, (borders Elbonia).

Comment: @BDL Because the main reason anyone feels "unwelcome" is because they made low quality posts and someone told them so. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362532/1394393 The claims of racism and sexism SO leveraged in its blog were utter nonsense. Besides this, SO demonstrably doesn't believe that using nice words at every possible moment is the correct way to address problems (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/1394393), meaning that the entire push is disingenuous. The only thing we can actually change to be more "welcoming" is to drop criticism and quality control.

Comment: @NicolBolas Last week, as a test, I went through the most recent C++ questions and flagged every comment that could be construed (in bad faith) as being snarky; within 5 minutes I'd flagged more than a dozen, including some from +100k users. All these flags were marked helpful, and as far as I could tell, all the comments were removed. Then the next day I did the same thing, and two thirds were declined. So it's a bit of a lottery, depending on which moderator handles your flags. But some will obviously remove anything that's flagged.

Comment: @m69: That's an interesting experiment. Have you considered trying it again, only this time record (via screenshots) what you flag and which ones get removed? I'd love to see an MSO question that involved such genuine data about what is being removed and what isn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas Unfortunately I didn't think of documenting the whole thing, partially because I didn't expect the result to be so spectacular. (And I'm not sure I should try that sort of thing again.) But there was nothing I would have flagged under normal circumstances, just the regular sort of comments you get under all bad questions in the C++ tag, like "why would you want to do that?" or "I don't see a question here".

Comment: @m69: To be honest, "why would you want to do that" is probably something best left unsaid. And I say this as someone who does on occasion write that. It's just not helpful, not unless it's a clear XY problem. Particularly in the C++ world, there are so many coding styles that we have to be ready to deal with code that we would probably rather we didn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas Even so, we could assume good faith, and see it as a request for more background information. For all we know, the person who writes such a comment is planning to check back later and write an answer once the asker has demonstrated that he has good reason to request a seemingly strange thing.

Comment: How would you feel about putting the ads back for high rep users, in exchange for cracking down on Elbonians?

Comment: I couldn't agree more with this.

Comment: Whatever we think of the course and the actions the team have taken over this issue, I haven't seen any indication that they are to be attributed to greed rather than a genuine desire to right a perceived wrong. Other actions are much more clearly attributable to revenue generation, like shoving a giant signup form in the faces of unregistered users (which they rolled back) and integrating Jobs with the site as tightly as possible (arguably still fairly tasteful). But the tension between exclusion vs. inclusion has always existed, with even the Founding Fathers Jeff and Joel on different sides

Comment: I've mentioned this elsewhere, but I've been to other sites that tried to be more "welcoming" since the 1990s, including Userfriendly, techrepublic, et cetera.  Whenever anyone asked a question, the result would be a bit of snark, foolishness, and then meaningful answers.  Then the crackdown came, then the regulars would say "what's the deal", then the powers that be would say "If you don't like it, leave".  Then we did.  SO is now moving into the "If you don't like it, leave" phase.

Comment: I really dislike this answer.  I wasn't a "professional" when I started using Stack Overflow.  I wasn't even a "professional" when I stopped just lurking and actually made an account here.  I was a college student who thought I had jumped in WAY over my head.  It was only through learning, trial and error, and using tools like Stack Overflow that I became a professional.  With this answer's mentality, I never would have found a place here and I wouldn't be half the programmer that I am today.  We all have to learn somewhere; no one starts as a professional.

Comment: @Kalmino that's exactly why the site should be welcoming, the person ignorantly posting a bad question today could become a valuable contributor tomorrow. Posting a comment to help someone along furthers that process much more than a simple downvote.

Comment: @Mark On its face what you say is very true and very valuable. The truth, unfortunately, is that commenting this way on every downvote ends up with most of your comments ignored, a bunch of them flagged, a meta post about how rude you are (if unlucky) and a MASSIVE amount of pushback and ad hominem. No wonder there is fatigue amongst curators. It's disheartening to post a comment to help someone and be told you are rude and should be more welcoming (or that you're toxic, or elitist or whatever). I'm ALL for respect and welcoming new users. Why can't people give the same respect they expect?

Comment: @Kalmino If there had been no professionals to ask, but just other confused students, would you have learnt anything of value from the site? Supposedly SO was once for "professional and enthusiast programmers". Enthusiasts being students and others who have a genuine interest to learn and improve.

Comment: Those who have been around long enough know that everything in this answer is true. The site quality has dropped significantly since the "Atwood era". Those who are asking why critics are still around - there is no alternative site to move to. If a similar site to SO with higher quality standards would be created, I would drop my SO membership instantly and move there, no regrets. Seems like a very easy way to steal the whole of SO's business through competition. Now, if only there were some web designers around on SO, who'd like to get rich...

Comment: Fully agree. SO's "rudeness" (just feels rude when not understanding the system) is what made me use this site in a proper way and I always considered it to be sign of quality. After your first question gets corrected by harsh comments, you realize quite quickly what makes a good, spot-on question. People are not interested if this is your aunt's cousins new PC she bought off that flea marked on last week's fair. If any comments that could make someone feel uncomfortable, because they realize that the question doesn't meet the quality standards required here, will be deleted, the site is dead.

Comment: SO has gone the way of other social media, time to dump it and look for alternatives. The thin skinned are taking over the world. Hope I didn't offend anyone because I don't care to be here, nothing personal just tired of listening to people whine about how their feelings got hurt.

Comment: There is already a SO clone on Github, forget the name of it Forum dot net or something like that but it's a good start. But with these sites it's critical mass that makes them useful not the software alone. That's how they are able to move to mass censorship like they are now. Tough times.

Comment: The advertising model for monetizing the Internet is a significant problem. I think there’s a solution. I blogged about it.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII Where's your blog at?

Comment: `Stack Exchange (...) are no longer interested in the founding tenets of Stack Overflow - high-quality questions and answers by professional programmers.` I think you should change your references to "professional programmers" and leave it as "professionals". Nowadays there are plenty of high value users for whom on the SE network who are not programmers.

Comment: @xDaizu Quality does not appear to be a problem for other sites.

Comment: @IanKemp Even if that's true (which I do not know if it is), I think SE is still interested in high-quality questions and answer by professional (mathematicians, biologists, teachers, parents, chess players,...)

Comment: @xDaizu This answer is posted on meta.SO for a reason: because it applies to Stack Overflow specifically. Stack Exchange may be comprised of a bunch of different sites, but in reality it's 90% Stack Overflow and 10% "the rest", and of course management is going to focus on the 90%.

Comment: I'm not really buying the "they just want money" argument - I'm more than willing to give SE the benefit of the doubt and say that they genuinely are concerned for people's happiness, not to mention a perceived negativity associated with their brand purely out of pride. However the end result is the same so otherwise your answer seems right.

Comment: Funny that not a single mod responds to this

Answer (score 150):

The new comment flag option "It's not relevant" is actually worse for this. This is gonna lead to a metric ton of invalid comment flags.

"It's not relevant" is incredibly subjective. One could argue answers in comments don't fall under that, yet they're supposed to be discouraged because they bypass the voting system.

A user who just wants their solution and cares about nothing else could see any clarification requests or critiques of their question as "It's not relevant". An answerer could see criticism of their answer they don't agree with as "It's not relevant".

Comment: When was this flag option introduced/renamed, and how will moderators handle it?

Comment: @CodeCaster As to 1) Yesterday (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313433/did-the-comment-flag-dialog-change-will-there-be-future-dialog-changes)) as to 2) no idea. The post I linked mentions that this was done ahead of the new CoC taking full force when there'll be 2 distinct categories for r/a flags on comments.

Comment: A -really- odd choice of label. Now mods are going to have to judge relevance? Seems like the usual "instantly delete" choice that is basically to be implied as "needs to go, but not rude/abusive".

Comment: If it's a comment about a technical clarification, I can't see how the mods can be expected to know what is, or is not, relevant, (in general - sure there are mods who have plenty skills on some language tags, but not all will be covered).

Comment: Actually I think people will flag **much less**, because I can't remember the last time I flagged a comment that wasn't at least somehow relevant to the question.

Comment: @Dukeling Again, it is subjective. Is "why the downvote? If you don't comment I can't know what's wrong" a relevant comment? In my opinion, it is generally uncalled for, and best kept away. The struggle is real.

Comment: @Magisch we can now see who's flagged a comment - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313155/59303 - so if it's the post owner flagging we can double check to see if they are trying to stifle dissent or not.

Comment: @ChrisF My answer didn't (or didn't intend to) insinuate that mods would abide that kind of conduct, but that a lot more invalid flags would be raised as a result of the confusing wording.

Comment: @Magisch - indeed. I was just pointing out that we'd become aware quite quickly if people were raising vexatious flags and hopefully nip it in the bud.

Comment: @E_net4 Uncalled for, not constructive and too chatty, but still relevant, although perhaps my definition of "relevant" is too close to "related".

Comment: "*Metric ton of invalid comment flags*": only if mods don't delete on sight anything with a flag.

Comment: not-relevant means more comments can stay. If they're discussing the post, it means they can stay. If they're discussing flying kites, then they go.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Is that the goal here? Allowing more comments to stay that get deleted under current policy?

Comment: @Magisch I actually have no idea lol I'm not sure what it means... *must remember to find out*

Comment: I don't find it very welcoming to write *"his solution"*. What about *"her solution"*?

Comment: "*An answerer could see criticism of their answer they don't agree with as "It's not relevant".*" An answerer could see them as "Rude or Abusive" too. That doesn't mean they are or will be deleted as such. Flagging is not deletion.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Indeed, and we already get a fair amount of rude/abusive flags on harmless comments of that exact nature. Some comments have keywords like "accept" that cause instant deletion by a single flag, though, regardless of the context in which those keywords are used. Additionally, the flags will get validated should the answerer choose to delete their answer while the flags are still pending.

Comment: @BoltClock so, just whole words without further punctuation?  Would 'accept()'  also be subject to instant deletion by a single flag?

Comment: @Martin James: Not sure. Test it: accept()

Comment: @BoltClock Doesn't seem to be the case. Maybe moderator posts are exempt: accept() .

Comment: @E_net4: "Why the downvote?" is predominantly useless for the _current_ downvote (as the downvoter has already left and probably won't come back since he's not tagged). However, I do think it has value for _future_ downvoters, as it helps them understand that adding a comment to the downvote is helpful.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sure, you can flag what you want. But it's much easier for a mod to discern abuse (which can be evaluated by the comment itself) as opposed to discerning relevance (which requires knowledge about the question, answer, topic, field, ...)

Comment: @Flater The fact that something has downvotes is not by itself an incentive to comment. It does not really have to be. Of course users "want" to know why their own content was downvoted, but I do not believe that this needs to be made explicit. And whoever agrees to provide additional feedback after some other downvote is also willing to face the respective consequences, even though the downvote could not be on their side. My main point is such comments will too often contribute negatively to the site, to the point that clearing them does more good than harm.

Comment: @E_net4 Not providing feedback leads to users not improving which leads to users repeating the same quality issues in future answers. You can't expect people to learn something by a -1 with no clarification. Is the downvote an issue with the correctness of the answer? The quality? Because the downvoter personally disagreed? A downvote by itself servers the purpose of SO (rating) but it does not serve the purpose of the poster (understanding what they did wrong). Some comments being unfairly negative or hostile is not a reason to avoid comments altogether. This is why we moderate things.

Comment: @Flater These matters inevitably intertwine, because it's a major reason why feedback on downvotes is not mandatory. No levels of moderation are going to be enough for hit-and-run hostility tactics employed by certain users. As you might imagine, unfairly negative and hostile comments, regardless of being from users to OPs or from OPs to other users, can hurt even after they are gone. But there is a clear difference here: while OPs could be just receiving terse, brusque feedback on their content, curators are not given **anything** positive back. They are bitten for an attempt to feed them.

Comment: With that said: there were initiatives from Stack Overflow to have teams of mentors to raise some sort of hand-guidance systems towards question improvements. That would make it not just an incentive. The problem is that this doesn't scale.

Comment: @E_net4 'hand-guidance systems towards question improvements' lol, sounds like SO curators being used as sock puppets to write questions:)

Comment: @Flater - I'm a little at a loss as to why (and *how* with the new guidelines) I would ever want to explain a downvote. I would presume answering with "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." is about as welcoming as explaining that "The duplicate I just voted to close with was the result directly under yours when I Googled your question title." This exercise in welcomeness is incentivizing my drive by down voting, because in the tags that I follow, there are a ton of questions that meet or exceed the stated criteria for hitting the down arrow.

Comment: @Comintern So you're aware of the stated criteria. But the poster apparently is not. I presume we're all here to help each other out, so I'm a bit baffled by the assertion that there's no reason to give meaningful feedback.

Comment: @Flater I don't think we asserted that. And feedback is still given, although not every time. Because every once in a while, someone refuses to read [ask] because they don't want to be told they are asking bad questions. And this part is the one that feels more actionable: we must make our users ask better questions from the start.

Comment: @E_net4_ I think we're talking about different things. I was under the impression we were focusing on "why you would ever want to explain a downvote" (as per your comment). If a posters **refuses** to read How to Ask, then he's must've already been told that he should read it. Which means that feedback is already given, the downvote was explained. _"someone refuses to read How to Ask because they don't want to be told they are asking bad questions"_ also seems contradictory. Not wanting to be told your question is bad is a reason **to read** How To Ask, not a reason to refuse to read it.

Comment: And at least this site is about coding. You should see history.se, wordlbuilding.se and politics.se, where the "It's not relevant" comment flags are routinely abused to express ideological differences, and to suppress any comments made by "the other side".

Answer (score 36):

The inverse perspective of [Ian Kemp's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371911/839601) (from a person positively impacted by *you, the experts*) below.

---

As a user who predominately *asks* questions instead of *answering*, this is terrifying (okay, I may be exaggerating a *bit*..). But quite honestly, the only reason I am able to be as efficient as I am, and have progressed as much as I have in the past 5 years as a developer *are the experts on Stack Overflow*. I would be crushed to find that the majority of experts are leaving because of bad user interactions and overzealous(?) moderators deleting comments that *are ultimately useful*.

As a newbie who relies on StackOverflow Q/A to be #1 Google result for any given programming-related search, **I beseech the moderators and those flagging to carefully consider the impact of their actions and their effects on the community**. Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange as a whole are my most-frequented sites for development of my own knowledge of the universe, and the *sole* reason this is possible is because SO/SE attracts knowledgeable people! These are the people who should *not* be driven away from the site(s)...

Obviously there is a bottom line to keep people visiting and get page views and such, but I wouldn't be an active user if I didn't always find interesting, thought-provoking and helpful information/advice on Stack Exchange. I'm sure I'm not the only one in the asks-and-reads-more-than-answers category of users who rely on knowledgable people like @CodeCaster.

I can't tell you how many times I've come to "oh duh, of course I should have mentioned that or clarified that point" because of someone like you guys dropping a comment. And I never feel upset or annoyed that a comment like that was made, because it helped me improve my question as well as my ability to formulate new ones in the future. My first few questions on SO were absolute crap but I feel that I've come a long way to better express myself and my problem(s) in the Q/A because of the effort you put in to help me with that. **I've grown as a person *because of you*.**

So please, flaggers and moderators, consider how you impact the community as a whole when you flag and delete. And experts, please know that there are people like me who are *incredibly* appreciative of your time and effort spent on crafting beautifully-written and informative answers, as well as time you spend helping the OP clarify and refine their question.

---

**And to answer the question**... *no, don't stop commenting*. The behavioral issue is not with *you, the commenter - it's the **flaggers** and **people dealing with the flags***. I'm not sure how to improve the system to make flagging and moderating more efficient and less prone to human error (I'm not sure that it *can* be at this point...), but the fact that comments like yours (OP/experts trying to help) get deleted when they clearly shouldn't be is just sad. And it does show lack of conscious on the part of those getting the comments deleted to the broader effect of their actions on the community - not only direct impact to the experts, but to those who rely on their knowledge every day. People need to be more conscious of that in general.

Comment: I should not feel bad to say that it sucks helping free loaders that come here looking to have someone else do their work. Why should we treat them like royalty when we worked very hard to get the knowledge we have and they want to use it for free, and are probably H1B's to boot taking our job. If the talent leaves, they have no help, works like socialism and money.

Comment: Can everyone stop being offended or offensive for for a while? As my grandmother said; If you have nothing nice to say don't say anything, The intensity and argument over the same topics seem to be no more than an excuse to trade "witty" insults and relieve tempers. It's exhausting.  People need to learn to walk away. Needing to have the last word is **not** a character strength.

Answer (score -9):

Comments are supposed to *request* clarifications and *suggest* improvements. They're the gentlest tool available, and sometimes you need a hammer made of sterner stuff than rubber to knock a problem in place. Comments are also meant to be transient - and have always been, by design.

The problem though with assuming that comments are not transient and somehow some comments are worth keeping around is - well, someone needs to make that decision. Sometimes more than once. It's not always the same person, and there's *often* a better place to put that information. Over time I've come to a suspicion that more or less, we're all doing comments wrong, and that some recent experiments - that they should be restricted to requests for clarification and such might work better.

As for comments suggesting fixes -

[You're leading the horse to water. You can't always get the equine hydrated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can_lead_a_horse_to_water,_but_you_can%27t_make_it_drink). If there's *major* issues that an OP is refusing to fix, and you can find an appropriate reason, close. Otherwise downvote. There's no point with yelling at a user in comments, or otherwise getting worked up. If the question is bad, rather than getting angry at the user, and posting a comment that's, well less than nice, just vote appropriately.

As for no longer needed flags. Flags are a request for attention. While in most cases and sites, these are relatively easy - SO... kind of has a problem of scale. I've actually suggested encouraging people to clean up after themselves as a solution.

If it's an extremely good comment that somehow rises above its humble roots as a 3rd class citizen, and acts as a shining beacon of truth and light... ehh. Hopefully it's left alone. Otherwise, might be worth having a quiet word with a moderator about it. Those are rare, in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, it's entirely appropriate to vote to close a question that has problems that merit closure.  That's not a reason to delete any comments on that post with more specific information on what the post does wrong, and how it can be improved.  Likewise, that people can downvote such a post isn't a reason to delete such comments.  A comment shouldn't need to be "a shining beacon of truth and light" to not get deleted.  Just your typical comment explaining how a question or answer could be made better, of the type that happens thousands of times a day, is fine, and shouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score -13):

I agree with your assessment, but I'd lean the other way. Instead of banning comments, I'd simply redirect them to a place they belong yet stay away from the pure Q&A aspect of the site. The chat room isn't cutting it.

I am aware that I personally skirt the line of comment discussions more than I should. That doesn't mean I don't understand the intention of SO/SE to remain QA-focused and not become a discussion board.

However, I do see value in a *reasonable* discussion on *some particular* topics. Not to use it as an ongoig chat, but some issues need deeper diagnosis, e.g. when they are rooted in a multi-layered misunderstanding. Some problems are XYZABCDE problems. You can usually only get from E to X using *repeated* probing, which is currently impossible without having a comment chain.

The current setup is to post a rule ("no discussion in comments"), which is enforced subjectively by moderators. I don't think the current setup is working.

- Discussion threads only get removed when they get excessive. A short discussion thread never gets removed and therefore implicitly suggests to users that the posted comments were acceptable.
- There are cases where the the first comment in a discussion thread was a *valid* comment to the answer, but it spawned a subsequent discussion in and of itself. When the thread gets removed, the first comment is often removed as well.

  - This makes it highly likely that someone else is going to post the same comment again (unaware of the removed comment), thus repeating the cycle.
  - I think it's realistic to say that most people are not going to browse through an extended chat history to check if their intended comment has been posted before. *Even if we agree that they should*, that doesn't mean they will do so.
- The current rule can often be abused (intentionally or not) when the poster wishes to remove the feedback.

  - The current zero tolerance discussion policy allows for people to (disingenuously) call out valid feedback as unnecessary discussion, in the hopes of an errant mod agreeing with them. At best, they get what they want; at worst, they've likely sparked a debate which will end up getting deleted anyway.
  - Repeatedly refuting a flaw in your answer, especially when either ignoring the comments or dodging the topic, inherently grows the thread so it gets deleted (including the first comment which pointed out a relevant flaw/error in the answer).
  - I've seen cases where people invalidate received feedback with the deadend "post your own answer then" or "no discussions are allowed" argument, which distracts from the feedback by implicitly suggesting that they *are* correct but simply can't tell you because it would break the rules.
  - If posters are able to have feedback removed from sight by filibustering, and we agree that this is a correct system, then we should simply give posters the ability to remove comments to their own posts. I don't think this is a good decision, but it's at least better than giving them the option to inescapable cause a comment deletion which requires mod attention.
- In the case of XYZABCDE problems, the current system prevents us from actually drilling down to the core of a problem. It only allows simple question/answer statements and makes it very hard to challenge underlying false assumptions that the OP (or answerer) has built their question (or answer) on. Sometimes, it's nigh impossible to ask for clarification (= comment) without suggesting a counter solution (= answer); especially if you suspect that the OP simply wasn't aware of the counter solution.

  - If you write a question comment "Why did you do A instead of B?", people are liable to respond "you should post B as an answer then".
  - If you post B as an answer, people are liable to respond "but OP is asking about A. You can't *know* that he actually needs B instead of A!".
- The sheer volume of comment discussions strongly suggests that a significant part of the community sees value in having the discussion.

---

**Redirecting comments to a place they belong**.

I think there's a very simple solution to address a lot of the mentioned issues. If we adapt to a tree-style comment chain (think: Reddit) where comments are collapsed by default, then everyone gets what they want:

- Q&A purists either ignore all comments, or only focus on top-level comments. They don't click through the hierarchy.
- Feedback to comments exists, but is only visible to those who go looking for it.
- The hierarchical nature of the comments makes it easier to look if someone else posted *your* feedback already (compare to reading a flat list like the chat/comment history)
- Only people who are interested in reading/writing lengthy discussions will drill down to a comment level of lengthy discussions.
- The mods don't need to police the comment threads as much (at least in terms of assessing if something is a discussion and being expected to clean them up)
- The chat room can still be used for chatting. Comment discussions are different from chatting. When they are on-topic for a posted question, they are essentially a back-and-forth Q&A.
- Optional: while trees are collapsed by default, we could allow for a system where sufficiently upvoted child comments are made visible by default. This is similar to us currently allowing some *meaningful* responses to comments.

Comment: I agree that valid comment discussions are very different than chatting.  Many times in order to write an answer you need clarification.  If you try to write an answer without all the information and asking for clarification  people will start down voting it even though your intent is to create a full answer.  If you like answering potentially interesting questions with very good answers this whole system is very frustrating. Also I hate the idea that I'm supposed to go chat privately in real time with a stranger.

Answer (score -16):

Controversial statement of the week:

## Stop commentating.  It's not accomplishing what you think it is.

Here's why I feel strongly about this.  Comments are genuinely the red-headed stepchild of the entire network.  They're given this otherworldly status and importance on the site as a whole from every level of participant, but they severely lack any sort of infrastructure or ecosystem to *support* this otherworldly status.

To spell it out, we use comments for:

- clarifying questions
- remarks
- feedback
- banter

...most of which has some valuable place on the site.

**However**, the only real stated value for comments is in the clarifying questions aspect.  The site just allows us to *abuse* comments to fill the other niches we want it to.

Explicitly, to your example...

> I commented something along the lines of:
>
> > Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. This is a simple
> >     indexof+substring or regex operation.

...such a comment is easily "feedback" at best, since the desired message (please show what you've tried) is buried under twelve feet of cement by the impulsive follow-up remark "simple".

---

Suffice it to say, but comments are not the magic tool or panacea we want them to be.  Adding feedback to a question asking them to improve the situation

## does *not* help

and we need to stop lying to ourselves.  The only *real* tools at our disposal to get the point across that their question needs to improve are **downvotes** and **closure votes**, and we need to be as generous with them as we are with commentating.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Will it? That has not been my experience. At least, not in the tags I patrol. But then, I don't go to the tags with the heaviest populations.

Comment: @CodeCaster Assuming the purpose of the downvote was to make it scored negative, sure, but if your purpose is just to indicate you find it not useful or low quality... it serves it's purpose regardless of whoever else votes on it. Not voting because it's gonna be reversed is counterintuitive. It's why people upvoting to reverse it is a problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  So stop shouting at the wind and direct Stack Overflow Community leaders to suggestions which *improve* how we users can moderate.  It's beyond clear that the current system is broken.  Instead of whispering and being polite about it, shout about this issue and don't *stop* shouting about it until it gets fixed.

Comment: @Makoto: Exactly what issue is it that we're supposed to be shouting about?

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Take your pick - the fact that user moderation is ineffective since we can't reliably moderate poor content, the fact that duplication tracking is so hard because there's no support for it, the fact that actions taken (e.g. downvotes/close votes) still get us branded as being "mean" somehow when all we're trying to do is improve the site, the fact that the new CoC is attempting to codify a community and culture change towards us being "friendly" and "welcoming" without any real clear definition of if that means we're going to *have* to comment every time we downvote/close...

Comment: @NicolBolas:  I'm sure there's a ton more.  This is easily the nth question on comments that's cropped up in the last few months yet we haven't really heard a lot on how this is going to be "fixed", or if it's being considered at all by The Powers That Be™.

Comment: @Makoto: I don't know why you would think the CoC would require commenting for downvotes/close votes.

Comment: @Makoto: "*The only real tools at our disposal to get the point across that their question needs to improve are downvotes and closure votes*" There's evidence that this doesn't in fact "get the point across" about anything. I'm not saying that you shouldn't down/close vote. But you shouldn't do it based on the belief that it's some kind of teaching tool. It's merely a way to get rid of bad content, not to help people make good content.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  If enough of one's posts are downvoted/closed, they can no longer post or participate on the site.  There's even a *warning* given to one if they are starting to approach the threshold.  How does that *not* teach someone that their content is not acceptable here?  And if it *doesn't*, then we need to explain to the Community team *how* it doesn't help.

Comment: @Makoto: You have a very odd definition of "teaching". Driving into a wall does not "teach" you the rules of the road. Jumping off a cliff does not "teach" you Newtonian mechanics. Someone smacking you every time you do a wrong thing does not "teach" you how to do the right thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas: In that case, there's a fundamental problem with the way the system teaches users that their content is bad.  We should call that out and explain how it could be better.

Comment: @NicolBolas In the flags you patrol I really doubt it, but in more popular less low level tags like Javascript I've seen this.  You both are right, but you are getting worse questions askers in general in PHP than C++, Vulkan and GLSL, the barrier to entry to even know to ask a question about those is much much higher.

Comment: re teaching: combine (still anonymous) downvotes with (nearly) required commenting with prepared comments from a list, like "what have you tried", "show code", etc. Allow freetext. If anything is extremely unwelcoming on this site, its uncommented downvotes leaving me guessing how I rubbed someone the wrong way.

Comment: @Harald:  The *system* failed you, not the community.  We shouldn't be required to explain why your post was downvoted or closed; it should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @Makoto you never have a bad day? You don't know anyone ever having a bad day? The system's description is mathematically provably complete and correct with regard to what a good question is? There is no chance that a question is actually good, but just rubbed someone the wrong way? There is no chance the downvoter just misunderstood something? If I downvote, I can be sure I am enlightened and can't be wrong? Huuuh, hard to believe, since I am human :-)

Comment: @Harald:  Because there's so much to unpack in this expression that actually literally does encompass about five years' worth of Meta history here, I can, without risk of irony, say that I am having a bad day.  However, the system makes no attempt to judge your question's value.  We community members *use* the system to judge the quality of your question.  We community members should be able to rely on the system to deliver the message of, "Hey, your question wasn't that great and here's what you can do to fix it," but it doesn't do that yet.

Comment: @Harald:  You take voting too personally.  We're not explicitly shouting at *you*.  We're only remarking on your content.  That disconnect leads to perceptions of "rudeness" and "hostility" which, in reality, existed before we voted on the question.

Comment: Even if it is not personal, it does not help. Standardized comments would actually help. I am not a teacher, but I am sure there is literature that says that just saying "wrong" without explanation is not an effective way of teaching.

Comment: @Harald:  You're making my point here; this is where the system needs to pick up the slack.  You're asking the community to explain what went wrong when the system has more than enough information to convey this on our behalf.  Asking community members to explain what happened or what went wrong simply doesn't scale, no matter how you want to stretch it.

Comment: @Harald: "*Even if it is not personal, it does not help.*" Doesn't help who? Voting helps users avoid poor questions. Closevotes stop people from answering bad questions. Both of these help the site. "*There is no chance that a question is actually good, but just rubbed someone the wrong way?*" If that's the case, then only one person will downvote it.

Comment: ... does not help the OP to improve the question. Which is particularly nasty for first time users --- just mentioning because there is all this hype going on about "unwelcoming comments". My point just was: unexplained downvotes are "unwelcoming", much more than a straight sentence what went wrong with a question.

Comment: Okay @Harald; I'm at my breaking point.  [What would *you* say to a question like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51641431/1079354)  Bear in mind that we get thousands of questions just like this every day with someone posting a question which is impossible for any of us to answer or do anything with.  You say downvoting without comment is unwelcoming.  How would you welcome them instead?

Comment: It now has the necessary "comment", but that needed moderator interaction. Already the first downvoter should have left this comment, selected from a predef list if they wish. Additional downvoters could select different comments or the same, thereby giving a helpful flag. Free format commenting or declining to comment should still be posdible, and downvote comments like this would stay anonymous.

Comment: If question closure gives more options to pinpoint what is exactly wrong, we start being really pedantic about picking the right option and you have the option to select what is missing from a question (because lets face it, usually its the basic common sense things such as relevant code or an error stacktrace so a simple selection list can do), I'd not be too apposed to the removal of the comment system. But right now, no way. If it is removed it will just move off-site without moderation or rules.

Comment: @Harald Shog9 experienced that, paradoxically, [**not** commenting on downvotes can actually teach better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/812149). I'll just say, the result of commenting on downvotes depends VERY much on what kind of person you are dealing with. Most won't learn; a few will. For those few, I will still comment (with or without downvote) how they can improve their post.

Comment: @Harald moderator interaction? The only people who closed the question are users, not diamond mod. It needed the same kind of interaction from me than it would if I had commented. I don't see how that's relevant.  Also, your idea is good, until you go in and implement it. I, for one, am tired of the ad hominem attacks thrown my way when I try to be welcoming and guide people to write better messages. It seems like I have to be welcoming, not just of new users, but of their crappy, unresearched questions, their abusive responses, and the myriads of insults they feel like throwing my way.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, if we lived in a world where everyone voted on every post based on how useful they think it is, then it wouldn't be problematic to downvote a post you think isn't useful.  The problem is lots of people will upvote negatively scored posts that they see *that wouldn't have upvoted if the score was positive*.  They're upvoting *to overcompensate for a downvote*, not because they think the post is useful.  Because of that behavior, you're often *helping* a bad answer by downvoting it, because of this overcompensation.  That it *shouldn't* happen doesn't change the fact that it does.

Comment: @Servy be the change you want to see.

Comment: @KevinB I already don't upvote bad posts just because they have a negative score.  That doesn't stop other people from doing it.  They don't notice my lack of action and take it as a signal that they should do the same.

Answer (score -19):

For some time now I have thought that this is the only way to salvage SO. And not by relying on our self-discipline to refrain from commentating. That won't work. I think we can all agree that the comments asking for clarification escalating to conflict will keep coming. No, simply remove the ability to comment on questions.

If a question cannot readily be answered, and we cannot comment on it, it will be downvoted and left with no answer.

Some askers will realise there is a problem with their question and work out how to improve it. Perhaps the majority will bemoan the lack of answers and head elsewhere. But they won't feel that SO was rude, just that their question was too hard for us.

But that's not really a problem. None of the experts here will have been drawn in to a fools errand to help an uncooperative asker to ask well. Conflict will have been avoided.

Ask yourself, how often does a really bad question get edited and improved to be considered good after guidance from comments? In my experience it is less than 1 in 25. That's a terrible hit rate.

So, remove the ability to comment on questions and I feel that the site will overall be better.

Comment: eh, i do think *the site* overall would be better in terms of less conflicts in comments (obviously removing comments would remove all conflicts in comments) but... it would also result in a lot of questions that currently get well answered... not getting well answered. Sure, it's because the question wasn't clear, but without comments we can't express that or tell the user what we need to provide a good answer. You'd certainly see an increase in NAA flags from answers trying to do what comments do.

Comment: @Kevin I accept that we might not be able to help some people that we can help now. But we spend so much time trying to help those that don't want to be helped, how do you know when you are going to get an asker that is receptive to being helped? I just think that we have to give up something good in order to extinguish a pain that is so much greater. Not I draw the distinction between users that are happy to have dialog, and accept constructive guidance (happy to be helped), and the unreceptive who want an answer *now* to the question that they asked whose flaws they can't accept.

Comment: I don't disagree... but there are people willing to do so, why not let them? flagging problematic comments seems to be working fine from my pov.

Comment: @Kevin It's the people willing to comment to guide askers to poor questions that lead to the conflict. Self restraint has clearly not worked. That's my opinion.

Comment: I'd hate to lose the ability to get a question clarified so that i can properly close it as a dupe rather than having to rely on getting 4 other people to vote unclear.

Comment: It wouldn't much matter if you couldn't close it. It would have negative votes and no answers. It would be cleaner up in due course. I accept that we would lose something. But I think that the gain would outweigh the loss.

Comment: We must destroy StackOverflow to save it. Or sump'n like that...

Comment: @Bob It's already completely broken though isn't it?

Comment: I feel that's throwing out the baby with the bathwater. But if we raised the bar for commenting on one's own post, perhaps? Or make it impossible to @-reply to another unless you have, say, 15 rep?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I was being sarcastic. SO is far from perfect, but that describes everything. You can't make a site just for "professional programmers" because that would require SO to define what a "professional programmer" is. Someone working as a programmer? Systems analysts? Business analysts? How about DBA's - they don't code (at least ours don't) but they're kind of related..? Students? Managers? (OK - we can agree - no managers - unless they code - or maybe not..?) And how do you enforce this? If you don't want to answer the questions that are asked, Just Say Nope and move on.

Comment: @Bob That's exactly what will happen, to the detriment of the site.

Comment: If there are no comments, there would be no way of improving questions or answers either, short of violently editing or turning it into wikipedia. We'd lose a quality assurance tool and the site would therefore get much worse, not better.

Comment: @Lundin That's if you believe that improving questions by leaving comments works. My experience is that the hit rate is incredibly low.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps it doesn't often work for questions, but it often works fine for answers.

Comment: @Lundin And my suggestion is to remove the ability to comment on questions, but retain it for answers. I think that the difference between comments on questions and answers speaks volumes to the underlying problem the site has with quality.

Comment: Save the comments, save the world.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well I get positive feeback from my comments because I'm especially kind to folks that only just joined. (Haven't had 1 single instance where one of my comments in the review queue caused a bad reaction.) I could point out a handful of users who take every opportunity to subtly mock and deride with their comments (but since they're passive-agressive it's hard to pinpoint their mockery for flagging).

Answer (score -38):

I think you're blowing this out of proportion. You're treating comment deletion (appropriate or not) as though you're being *sanctioned* in some way. You're not.

You commented. The OP didn't agree with it. So... what more do you want? Do you think that the continued presence of your comment will *make* them agree with it? I rather doubt it. So if the OP responded negatively, then your comment is only useful as a notation *to others* that someone thinks the question needs additional information.

Is that information critical to leave attached to that question?

I'm not saying that removing the comment was right or wrong. But it's not an indication that the comment itself is unwanted. It's an indication that the OP has decided not to comply, so the comment serves no further use.

Comment: I strongly disagree. `The OP has decided not to comply != the comment serves no further use`. I think that one of the ways new users learn how the system works and get used to it is by reading this kind of comments. On the other hand, when the comment gets removed, we can't blame them for thinking that the question has nothing wrong as the OP said.

Comment: Comments shouldn't just be directed at the OP, you should always consider how the wider audience will read them. I expect my comments to stick around forever, and if they're no longer relevant then *I'll* delete them.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Comments have never worked that way. Just look around MSO: the expectation of comments is that they're supposed to be subject to deletion. And it has been that way since the beginning.

Comment: I disagree. If the comment is left undeleted, it will prevent others from having to make the-same or similar comment if the questions needs code to show some work or show which part of the code is causing the issue. It will also get up-votes therefore making the OP rethink about his/her reply and add code to the question. Once the code is added the comment can now be deleted.

Comment: Comments are the most important means of spreading culture on the site. (It's why everyone is so keen on getting rid of totally negative/unproductive ones.) That's why they have relevance beyond the interaction with the OP, just like the question and its answers do. It's all for future readers as much as for the present ones.

Comment: @Pekka웃: By that reasoning, we shouldn't delete comments that requested information that was *provided*. After all, they still communicate that a user requested certain information, which was later provided. That's part of "spreading culture".

Comment: @NicolBolas: Everyone mouths the mantra of "comments can be deleted at any time for any reason", but in practice that expectation is not there. Compare with the very similar wording found in a great many website agreements that say "we can delete your account/remove your game achievements/terminate your license to use our software/whatever *for any reason, or no reason*." In other words, it reads like standard slightly-slimy exception-handling legalese that no one really expects to be routinely triggered. And indeed most comments *aren't* deleted.

Comment: The information that a particular comment is actively not complied with seems like wickedly valuable input for future commenters who can then choose to not make the same suggestions; comments become obsolete when they *have* been complied with. But it cannot be ignored that it indeed has always been communicated that comments can be deleted at any time (which does not say anything about how frequently it will happen, @NathanTuggy) so it cannot be berated that this documented freedom is exercised. I dislike it and will upvote any suggestion favouring change, but it's just the way it is.

Comment: @Gimby: If Twitter deleted your account because somebody got in a snit with you (and the Twitter ToS make it abundantly clear that they absolutely have that legal right), you might well be upset with them and complain. Saying "well they told you ahead of time they might do that" is *technically, legally true*, but unhelpful, and suggesting there was a real expectation of that is dubious in the extreme. In other words, the ephemerality of comments is largely a legal fiction.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that is comparing apples and oranges, it'd be more to the point if you take the example of removing a tweet. Then all of a sudden the impact is a lot lower.

Comment: Comments are very useful to future visitors.  Deleting them means that the same discussion will happen again and again, which just wastes everyone's time.  Comments that suggest improvements are vital, especially when they haven't been incorporated in the answer.  I cannot count the amount of times that a comment has held some crucial information.  I don't understand why deleting comments is seen as so important, when the site already has great ways of handling long comment chains (i.e. only showing the most upvoted comments).

Comment: @Gimby: So, if Twitter randomly removed 15% of your tweets, how would that come across? Sure, the degree of outrage depends on the overall importance of what was deleted. But the existence of expectation *doesn't*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "*In other words, the ephemerality of comments is largely a legal fiction.*" Except that it isn't because they frequently *do get deleted*. Whatever expectations you have in you head are not borne out in how SO works.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The idea that comments are designed to be ephemeral really is inherently true.  But, as [described in detail here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371866/please-dont-shoot-the-messenger-what-can-i-do-better#comment616162_371868) the problem is that it's not a valid justification for deleting any comment without any other reason.  The fact that the comment will *ideally*, eventually become obsolete, doesn't mean that you can delete any comment, because *that comment might not be obsolete yet*.

Comment: _"I think you're blowing this out of proportion. You're treating comment deletion (appropriate or not) as though you're being sanctioned in some way. You're not."_ You're right: the whole community is being sanctioned. Every comment of this form, when deleted, is a drop in the ocean of loss. We all lose.

Comment: Other than that you actually do have an interesting point here.

Comment: I _will_ say, again, that just because we are supposed to expect that comments _can_ be deleted, doesn't automatically mean that every comment _should_ be deleted, and as soon as possible at that. There's really no point in having them otherwise.

Answer (score -72):

I deleted the comment, as I believed it was no longer needed. It had been read by several people and noted. It serves no purpose to remain under the question. We cannot force people to make changes to their posts. We can only make suggestions.

If the post is off topic and the OP has ignored requests to improve it, the post should be closed. So vote to close it.

Comment: No, the comment hasn't served its purpose, as the OP ignored it and it was removed so others couldn't read it as well.

Comment: @CodeCaster do you want me to make my poem longer to address this issue?

Comment: The poem doesn't need to be longer / the message doesn't need to be stronger / Only this I want to say: / I think that comment should stay.

Comment: @CodeCaster there was nothing wrong with your comment. It was helpful. The issue is - there's so much friction in places and when people start flagging comments, it's sometimes just easier from the mod end to delete them.

Comment: If mods delete comments whenever there's a slight hint of friction because it's the easiest option, then you answered the question in the OP: yes, we should stop commenting altogether.

Comment: @CodeCaster see my edit and the comment is undeleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616309/single-smtp-report#comment90198082_51616309

Comment: So the consensus is: you (as in: you, the moderators, not you personally) get a shitload of comment flags on any given day, and to prevent exhaustion, friction, discussion or whatever, when in doubt, you delete. That's not really inviting to put much effort in commenting. I'm not saying I'm particularly proud of that comment, or that it couldn't have been written in a more constructive way, but again, my question is about the pattern and not this particular comment.

Comment: I tend to agree with @CodeCaster here, sorry. Comments are often seen as something minor, not relevant, and not useful, but we forget **it takes time and effort to write comments**. And when such comments are deleted without thought just due to one single flag, that is not nice, and a good reason to simply stop commenting. (To be clear: I'm not talking about the single comment in this question,  but in general. Plus, I don't blame the specific moderator deleting comments in response to flags. I'm complaining about the system as a whole)

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure what else the mods can do about it.  I'm not saying it's right, but it may be the least wrong thing when faced with an overwhelming workload - like downvoting with no comment on Sundays.

Comment: This answer was really not intended to be serious. It was just some fun. I'm sorry it's causing issue.. I can edit it.. Comments are extremely difficult in this political climate, it's like we're all walking on egg shells. *Don't shoot the messenger people*

Comment: @YvetteColomb nah - keep it going.  May as well have some fun during SO twighlight years..

Comment: ... by which I meant ' riddled with vampires'

Comment: @CodeCaster I've updated my answer to give some honest reasons behind why I delete comments. To try and clarify and put it into perspective from a mod view. Let me know if it helps. And yes point noted re- posting as a mod

Comment: *"If the comment is asking for clarification of a question and the question has been answered (satisfactorily), there's really no need to keep the comment"* I kinda disagree, if the question is unclear to someone there's a good chance it'll be unclear to someone else, and that might be the next person who comes in from a Google-search. Even if a question has an adequate answer it still benefits from being improved. Is the takeaway that we should CV as unclear instead?

Comment: @ivarni: It could go either way. Clarity is subjective - what one sees as an edit that clarifies the question might well have made it unnecessarily complicated, or worse, unclear, for someone else. Evaluate the question and its answer in tandem. Does the question completely rely on the answer to make sense? If so, it's probably unclear enough to vote to close. If the answer just happens to be something the asker did not try, then... the question is answered.

Comment: @BoltClock and the key to all this, is there's no close votes on it and the OP didn't vote to close it either. So what is it? Oh I want you to improve it, but it's on topic, so I won't close vote it?

Comment: @CodeCaster Comments have always been seen as ephemeral without any lifetime expectancy. They can be deleted at any time and for any reason.

Comment: *"Comments are extremely difficult in this political climate"*. Political climate? Off-topic on Stack Overflow, delete it.

Comment: "there was nothing wrong with your comment. It was helpful. The issue is - there's so much friction in places and when people start flagging comments, it's sometimes just easier from the mod end to delete them." - if deletion is the easiest solution in this case, this is a systemic issue. The easy solution should be to _not take any action_, as in, skip the flag. That's what reviewers in every single review queue are told they should do with cases which are not clear. Why does this guidance suddenly change to "just delete it" for the mod-only comment flag queue?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I generally don't vote on posts I find from meta, I was more interested in knowing if, in the general case, I should try to help an OP improve before voting, but I got my answer. Thanks.

Comment: My understanding of comments is that they are made to help clarify and improve questions. I am pretty sure it isn't what you mean, but the way this is written makes me think someone could post a crappy but on topic question, and comments to improve it wouldn't be welcomed because it has an answer.

Comment: _"I've noticed (anecdotally) that once two or more flags are raised on a thread, it increases the likelihood of a another flag, from a new user."_ Surely a causal relationship here is literally impossible.

Comment: _"In the long run we cannot control every interaction between people."_ But that's exactly what a "delete-by-default" policy does!

Comment: _"If the question is off topic, vote to close it. It's time to stop arguing with edge cases or hypotheticals. It's either on topic or it's not."_ Hardly! The number of debates about whether something fits SE's nebulous rules shows that whether something is on topic or not is often _highly subjective_. Just because you have made a decision doesn't mean it's a clear-cut black-and-white choice ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We all have long ago accepted that comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time and for any reason. That, though, in and of itself, does not relieve us of our right to question the decision to _actually do so_ in specific cases. Otherwise, honestly, you may as well just remove the comment feature altogether because if "can be deleted" becomes "will almost always be deleted, almost immediately" there remains pretty much no point in having them in the first place.

Comment: Nice poem, even though I disagree  I've long thought it's time to revisit the "comments are for deletion anyway" mantra. So many comments clearly contain valuable information that can't be incorporated into an answer. Good, productive comments can take as much time to craft as do good answers, and I for one am not willing to invest that time if comment deletionism is set to become the norm.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In what way does the comment we're discussing here add any real value? I don't see it, so deletion is perfectly fine in my book.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In what way is prompting a Stack Overflow question-asker to include problem-solving evidence in their question not of value?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Totally agree with you on this. I suggested on MSE (in a comment) that perhaps we should be voting comments down as well as up that got a surprising amount of votes, perhaps that's how we make comments more of a first class feature and treat them like posts.

Comment: @DavidG that may just work. But what would the downvote achieve? How would it work?

Comment: @YvetteColomb The same as votes on posts? I don't know really, needs to be thought about far more than my throwing-in-the-hand-grenade style comment has had.For reference, [my original comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311737/lets-hold-language-in-comments-to-the-same-standard-as-posts#comment1019039_311737) was on a post titled *Let's hold language in comments to the same standard as posts*

Comment: @DavidG but would it fade out comments

Comment: Is that such a bad idea? Comments without votes already get hidden completely by default when there's enough of them

Comment: @DavidG no, not at all. I was enquiring, but failed to put the "?" :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The comment in the question does no such things. It basically just says "RTFM how SO work" and then trivializes the problem of the OP. If that is what you post as a comment, consider not posting it or expect it to be deleted, or consider how you phrase your comment to actually be helpful. That comment serves for the satisfaction/release of the poster, not for the benefit of the recipient IMO.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I cannot comprehend how you've read it that way. Perhaps you forgot to assume good faith, or you missed out a few words

Comment: "erring on the side of deletion can be the wisest choice." This is a sentiment that really sticks out and is bound to be unpopular. It should be explained (the extent of willingness to err, and justification behind it - such as pro/con tradeoffs) in greater detail.

Comment: @YvetteColomb what on earth has happened that you [completely flipped in less than three month](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368072/620382)? Is it not completely clear that deleting these comments undermines our ability to improve this site? It would be nice if moderators stepped in and clarified how the site works in case of *friction* - but if you understandably cannot do that due to workload, then in the name of all that is secular and non-vulgar don't impede us to do so.

Comment: Random idea: Remove comments asking for improvements only after closing a question - **only then** you may begin to argue that it is no longer needed given the prominently displayed close reason which also explains nicely how to improve the post. If the comment goes into specific details of what needs to be improved, include those in a custom close reason.

Comment: This whole _"The comment was read so it can be deleted"_ mantra is nonsense at best. The problem with the comment was that it was utterly useless, not that it was "read".